# C dynamically growing array

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I have a program that reads a "raw" list of in-game entities, and I intend to make an array holding an index number (int) of an indeterminate number of entities, for processing various things. I would like to avoid using too much memory or CPU for keeping such indexes...

A quick and dirty solution I use so far is to declare, in the main processing function (local focus) the array with a size of the maximum game entities, and another integer to keep track of how many have been added to the list.
This isn't satisfactory, as every list holds 3000+ arrays, which isn't that much, but feels like a waste, since I'll possible use the solution for 6-7 lists for varying functions.

I haven't found any C (not C++ or C#) specific solutions to achieve this. I can use pointers, but I am a bit afraid of using them (unless it's the only possible way).

The arrays do not leave the local function scope (they are to be passed to a function, then discarded), in case that changes things.

If pointers are the only solution, how can I keep track of them to avoid leaks?

Comment: This is a (very, very small) problem in C, but how did you miss all the C++ and C# solutions for this?

Comment: "If pointers are the only solution, how can I keep track of them to avoid leaks?" Care, attention, and valgrind. This is exactly why people are so afraid if C in the first place.

Comment: You cannot use C effectively without using pointers. Don't be afraid.

Comment: without big libs only one function for all also for structs eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456446/a-good-c-equivalent-of-stl-vector/3463498#3463498

Comment: Using C without pointers is like using a car without fuel.

Comment: C is a chainsaw with all the safeties removed. Don't worry though, if you lose a finger or a hand, C will give you another. (Another chainsaw that is.)

Answer (score 306, accepted):

> I can use pointers, but I am a bit afraid of using them.

If you need a dynamic array, you can't escape pointers. Why are you afraid though? They won't bite (as long as you're careful, that is). There's no built-in dynamic array in C, you'll just have to write one yourself. In C++, you can use the built-in [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) class. C# and just about every other high-level language also have some similar class that manages dynamic arrays for you.

If you do plan to write your own, here's something to get you started: most dynamic array implementations work by starting off with an array of some (small) default size, then whenever you run out of space when adding a new element, double the size of the array. As you can see in the example below, it's not very difficult at all: (I've omitted safety checks for brevity)

```
typedef struct {
  int *array;
  size_t used;
  size_t size;
} Array;

void initArray(Array *a, size_t initialSize) {
  a->array = malloc(initialSize * sizeof(int));
  a->used = 0;
  a->size = initialSize;
}

void insertArray(Array *a, int element) {
  // a->used is the number of used entries, because a->array[a->used++] updates a->used only *after* the array has been accessed.
  // Therefore a->used can go up to a->size 
  if (a->used == a->size) {
    a->size *= 2;
    a->array = realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(int));
  }
  a->array[a->used++] = element;
}

void freeArray(Array *a) {
  free(a->array);
  a->array = NULL;
  a->used = a->size = 0;
}
```

Using it is just as simple:

```
Array a;
int i;

initArray(&a, 5);  // initially 5 elements
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  insertArray(&a, i);  // automatically resizes as necessary
printf("%d\n", a.array[9]);  // print 10th element
printf("%d\n", a.used);  // print number of elements
freeArray(&a);
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. I implemented the specific function using a big array, but will implement other similar things using this, and after I get it controlled, change the others back :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. A `removeArray` method that gets rid of the last element would also be neat. If you allow it, I will add it to your code sample.

Comment: %d and size_t... bit of a no-no there.  If you use C99 or later, can take advantage of the addition of %z

Comment: Never omit safety checks with memory allocation and reallocation.

Comment: I don't think your size would ever grow from zero because it's only multiplicative (ie 0*2 = 0). Adding a constant helps avoid lots of scrappy copies at the start and prevents this bootstraping issue. I would also recommend usually using a smaller multiplier than 2, to avoid risking wasting lots of space. n = (n*3)/2+8 is my usual favourite. But seriously, if you want to do something in C you need to get unscared of situations like this quick or change language. Using pointers is different to modern languages and can be confusing, but it's not complicated. I'm sure you'll be able to get it.

Comment: @DanSheppard where did `n = (n*3)/2+8` come from?

Comment: It's a performance tradeoff. If you double each time, then you sometimes have a 100% overhead and on average 50%. 3/2 gives you 50% worst and 25% typical. It's also close to the effective base of the Fibionacci sequence in the limit (phi) which is often praised and used for its "exponential but much less violently than base-2" characteristics, but easier to calculate. The +8 means that arrays which are reasonably small don't end up doing too many copies. It adds a multiplicative term allowing the array to quickly grow if its size is irrelevant. In specialist uses this should be tunable.

Comment: A function to remove from the array would be very convenient

Comment: @DanSheppard No matter the algorithm used, I would suspect that the professional way to grow the array would be to ensure that the allocated size is always a multiple of `_Alignof (int)`. Regardless of the array item type (which happens to be int, in this specific case).

Comment: @DanSheppard The larger the multiplier, the less copying to the new place needs to be done when the array is reallocated. So I would opt for using 4 or even 8 as multiplier. Most operating systems allocate physical storage to the virtual memory only when the given memory page is first written to. So having large unused space on the top of the array doesn't hurt much. The best is actually having a good estimate how many elements you will need and reserve that much space in the array before using it.

Comment: `a->array = (int *)realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(int));` will create a dangling pointer and a leak if the call fails.

Comment: What would the code be if you didn't omit safety checks ?

Comment: @Accountant to say that's "omitted" is a bit generous as everything necessary to handle an error gracefully is absent, so we have to handle the errors by using `exit`. `int *temp = realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof *temp); if (!temp) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } a->array = temp;`

Comment: Doubling the size of the buffer is usually not optimal. A growth rate of about 1.5 is usually better. See this question for further information: [What is the ideal growth rate for a dynamically allocated array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1100311/12149471)

Answer (score 32):

One simple solution involves [`mmap`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html). This is great if you can tolerate a POSIX solution. Just map a whole page and guard against overflows, since `realloc` would fail for such values anyway. Modern OSes won't commit to the whole lot until you use it, and you can truncate files if you want.

Alternatively, there's `realloc`. As with everything that seems scarier at first than it was later, the best way to get over the initial fear is to **immerse yourself into the discomfort of the unknown**! It is at times like that which we learn the most, after all.

Unfortunately, there are limitations. While you're still learning to use a function, you shouldn't assume the role of a teacher, for example. I often read answers from those who seemingly don't know how to use `realloc` (i.e. *the currently accepted answer!*) telling others how to use it incorrectly, occasionally under the guise that they've *omitted error handling*, even though this is a common pitfall which needs mention. [Here's an answer explaining how to use `realloc` correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21006798/1989425). **Take note that the answer is storing the return value into a *different* variable in order to perform error checking.**

Every time you call a function, and every time you use an array, you are using a pointer. The conversions are occurring implicitly, which if anything should be even scarier, as it's the things we don't see which often cause the most problems. For example, memory leaks...

Array operators are pointer operators. `array[x]` is really a shortcut for `*(array + x)`, which can be broken down into: `*` and `(array + x)`. It's most likely that the `*` is what confuses you. We can further eliminate the addition from the problem by assuming `x` to be `0`, thus, `array[0]` becomes `*array` because adding `0` won't change the value...

... and thus we can see that `*array` is equivalent to `array[0]`. You can use one where you want to use the other, and vice versa. Array operators are pointer operators.

`malloc`, `realloc` and friends don't *invent* the concept of a pointer which you've been using all along; they merely *use* this to implement some other feature, which is a different form of storage duration, most suitable when you desire *drastic, dynamic changes in size*.

It is a shame that the currently accepted answer *also* goes against the grain of [some other very well-founded advice on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), and at the same time, misses an opportunity to introduce a little-known feature which shines for exactly this usecase: flexible array members! That's actually a *pretty broken* answer... :(

When you define your `struct`, declare your array *at the end* of the structure, without any upper bound. For example:

```
struct int_list {
    size_t size;
    int value[];
};
```

This will allow you to unite your array of `int` into the same allocation as your `count`, and having them bound like this can be *very handy*!

`sizeof (struct int_list)` will act as though `value` has a size of 0, so it'll tell you the size of the structure *with an empty list*. You still need to add to the size passed to `realloc` to specify the size of your list.

Another handy tip is to remember that `realloc(NULL, x)` is equivalent to `malloc(x)`, and we can use this to simplify our code. For example:

```
int push_back(struct int_list **fubar, int value) {
    size_t x = *fubar ? fubar[0]->size : 0
         , y = x + 1;

    if ((x & y) == 0) {
        void *temp = realloc(*fubar, sizeof **fubar
                                   + (x + y) * sizeof fubar[0]->value[0]);
        if (!temp) { return 1; }
        *fubar = temp; // or, if you like, `fubar[0] = temp;`
    }

    fubar[0]->value[x] = value;
    fubar[0]->size = y;
    return 0;
}

struct int_list *array = NULL;
```

The reason I chose to use `struct int_list **` as the first argument may not seem immediately obvious, but if you think about the second argument, any changes made to `value` from within `push_back` would not be visible to the function we're calling from, right? The same goes for the first argument, and we need to be able to modify our `array`, not just *here* but *possibly also in any other function/s we pass it to*...

`array` starts off pointing at nothing; it is an empty list. *Initialising* it is the same as adding to it. For example:

```
struct int_list *array = NULL;
if (!push_back(&array, 42)) {
    // success!
}
```

P.S. **Remember to `free(array);`** when you're done with it!

Comment: "`array[x]` is really a shortcut for `*(array + x)`, [...]" Are you sure about that???? See an exposition of their different behaviors: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c.

Comment: Alas, @C-Star-Puppy, the one reference your resource appears to not mention at all is the C standard. That is the specification by which your compilers must adhere to legally call themselves C compilers. Your resource doesn't seem to be contradicting my information at all. Nonetheless, the standard actually has some examples such as [this gem](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1) where it's revealed that `array[index]` is actually `ptr[index]` in disguise... *"The definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`"* You can't refute the std

Comment: Try this demonstration, @C-Star-Puppy: `int main(void) { unsigned char lower[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; for (size_t x = 0; x < sizeof lower - 1; x++) { putchar(x[lower]); } }`... You'll probably need to `#include <stdio.h>` and `<stddef.h>`... Do you see how I wrote `x[lower]` (with `x` being the integer type) rather than `lower[x]`? The C compiler doesn't care, because `*(lower + x)` is the same value as `*(x + lower)`, and `lower[x]` is the former where-as `x[lower]` is the latter. All of these expressions are equivalent. Try them out... see for yourself, if you can't take my word...

Comment: ... and then of course there's this part, which I've placed my own emphasis into, but you really should read the entire quote without emphasis: *"Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue**. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined."* The same is true for functions, btw.

Comment: Ohh and on one final note, @C-Star-Puppy, Microsoft C++ is not a C compiler and hasn't been one for almost 20 years. You can enable C89 mode, *suuuure*, but we have evolved beyond the late 1980s in computing. For more on that topic, I suggest reading [this article](https://www.infoq.com/news/2012/05/vs_c99_support)... and then switching to an actual C compiler such as `gcc` or `clang` for all of your C compilation, because you'll find there are so many packages that have adopted C99 features...

Comment: Yes, I heard here and there too that c evolved over time. I currently just started learning c and I’m using the first online compiler I found on the web, I hope that is fine, is it? Besides, when it comes to exact documentations of commands I’m using the iso c11 manual. :)

Comment: @C-Star-Puppy You should avoid any resource which tries to teach you that "Variable names in C are just labels". In the very same paragraph that the author of your resource tells you you should be "hacking on compilers" (I assume they mean understanding the lingo compiler devs use?), your author confuses one type of identifier with another. Sure, both "variable names" and labels are identifiers, but neither actually have *anything* to do with arrays and thus neither should be mentioned in the article you linked to. Consider `"hello world"`; what *variable name* does this *array* have?

Comment: @C-Star-Puppy In fact, that goes for all resources which neglect to mention one of the following: 1/ the POSIX manuals (usually available by Google searching for "opengroup `strcpy`" if you want to find the `strcpy` manual, for example) or 2/ in your case the C11 standard (though I think you should care far more about the C99 standard, if only for the mean time). Did you know [the `gcc` compiler manual refers to the standard](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html)? `clang` and Microsoft, too. They all do, and have to or else the compilers would be non-standard rubbish in our view.

Comment: There is one exception: K&R2e, our classic, "holy bible", which it turns out isn't actually our "holy bible" because it refers to the C89 standard... C89 is a good place to begin learning *most* of the features we know to be C nowadays.

Comment: Hello @autistic, I am trying to understand the (x & y) == 0 bitwise operation check you are doing here. I am not heavily experienced in programming. I understand this is a bitwise AND operation and I use bitwise operations in code. What I don't understand is what is this check doing in this instance?

Comment: Okay, so I wrote down all of the numbers on paper and I understand that this is basically finding all of the numbers 2^n-1 and reallocating when you reach that number. My question is, is there somewhere I can read more about this? Like how would I know that doing a bitwise AND operation with 2^n and 2^n-1 would result in 0.

Comment: @SeanPayne that's an [optimal test for powers of two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2). The array resizes to one less than each power of two so that `realloc` (a costly operation) is called much less. Furthermore, the size can theoretically reach `SIZE_MAX`, which is one less a power of two (we couldn't reach this number with a power of two). Mind you, there aren't many implementations that would permit an object of `SIZE_MAX` size in reality. I think perhaps one of those physical address extensions from the original P4-Quad era could've.

Comment: Thank you. The code you've provided is a good learning experience. It would be hard to delete elements with this implementation, correct? If you pop an element off the end and decrement size just after doing a realloc, you'd duplicate realloc calls on the next push. I'm assuming this is only if you want to continually grow an array and not worry about deletions?

Comment: @SeanPayne assuming `pop_back` is similar in logic to `push_back`, but with an `int *value` argument (and corresponding assignment to the pointed-at), `y = x - 1` and a guard against `x == 0`, perhaps tag the structure with a boolean, only set after `pop_back` `realloc`. The tag can serve the purpose of telling `push_back` when it doesn't need to `realloc` (on top of the existing logic), after which that tag likely needs to be unset. It seems premature optimisation once we inspect functions like `systrim` in [glibc malloc.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.c#L2735).

Comment: @autistic, thank you. That makes complete sense. I appreciate the detailed responses.

Comment: @SeanPayne In reflection to my suggestion, I neglected to mention an implementation for random deletion; I wanted to suggest `memmove` followed by a call to `pop_back` but then I realised all three of these functions have the same `realloc` logic, so that ought to be abstracted away like `int resize(struct int_list **, int delta)` where `delta` is used  in calculating `y = x + delta` so you can refer to that in all three functions. Also, I'm sure there's a really easy POSIX solution that hasn't been suggested; I might edit that in soonish.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow now. If you decide to update your answer above let me know. :)

Comment: @SeanPayne I just added a note at the start mentioning `mmap`. 

Comment: @SeanPayne I also realised I already wrote [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503954/how-to-implement-a-pop-function-that-returns-the-popped-element-i-e-the-dat/51729193#51729193), which answers a part of another of your questions, but implementing the functions as macros (and `resize` as `operate`). I'm not quite sure why I did that, but it's probably because professors will often scald students trying to abuse preprocessor macros.

Answer (score 13):

There are a couple of options I can think of.

1. Linked List. You can use a linked list to make a dynamically growing array like thing. But you won't be able to do `array[100]` without having to walk through `1-99` first. And it might not be that handy for you to use either.
2. Large array. Simply create an array with more than enough space for everything
3. Resizing array. Recreate the array once you know the size and/or create a new array every time you run out of space with some margin and copy all the data to the new array.
4. Linked List Array combination. Simply use an array with a fixed size and once you run out of space, create a new array and link to that (it would be wise to keep track of the array and the link to the next array in a struct).

It is hard to say what option would be best in your situation. Simply creating a large array is ofcourse one of the easiest solutions and shouldn't give you much problems unless it's really large.

Comment: How does seven arrays of 3264 integers sound for a modern-ish 2D game? If I am just being paranoid, the solution would be large array.

Comment: Both #1 and #4 here require using pointers and dynamic memory allocation anyhow.  I suggest using `realloc` with #3 - allocate the array a normal size, and then grow it whenever you run out.  `realloc` will handle copying your data if necessary.  As for the OP's question on memory management, you just need to `malloc` once at the start, `free` once at the end, and `realloc` each time you run out of room.  It's not too bad.

Comment: @Balkania: seven arrays of 3264 integers is a hair under 100KB.  That's not very much memory at all.

Comment: @Borealid: Hoh, I should really forget my ancient quickbasic times :P
I'll try to go for the large array to test the system, and dare venturing into the malloc later, I'll need to read a bit.

Comment: @Balkania: `7 * 3264 * 32 bit` sounds like `91.39 kilobytes`. Not that much by any standard these days ;)

Comment: This particular omission is a shame, because it isn't entirely obvious what should happen when `realloc` returns `NULL`: `a->array = (int *)realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(int));`... Perhaps it would've been best written as: `int *temp = realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof *a->array); a->array = temp;`... That way it would be obvious that whatever does happen needs to happen *before* the `NULL` value is assigned to `a->array` (if it is at all).

Comment: [Bjarne Stroustrup explaining why you shouldn't use linked lists](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo). Simply put, the  strength of a linked list is not in mimicking arrays.

Answer (score 6):

Building on **Matteo Furlans** design, when he said "*most dynamic array implementations work by starting off with an array of some (small) default size, then whenever you run out of space when adding a new element, double the size of the array*". The difference in the "**work in progress**" below is that it doesn't double in size, it aims at using only what is required. I have also omitted safety checks for simplicity...Also building on **brimboriums** idea, I have tried to add a delete function to the code...

The storage.h file looks like this...

```
#ifndef STORAGE_H
#define STORAGE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    typedef struct 
    {
        int *array;
        size_t size;
    } Array;

    void Array_Init(Array *array);
    void Array_Add(Array *array, int item);
    void Array_Delete(Array *array, int index);
    void Array_Free(Array *array);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* STORAGE_H */
```

The storage.c file looks like this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "storage.h"

/* Initialise an empty array */
void Array_Init(Array *array) 
{
    int *int_pointer;

    int_pointer = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

    if (int_pointer == NULL)
    {       
        printf("Unable to allocate memory, exiting.\n");
        free(int_pointer);
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        array->array = int_pointer; 
        array->size = 0;
    }
}

/* Dynamically add to end of an array */
void Array_Add(Array *array, int item) 
{
    int *int_pointer;

    array->size += 1;

    int_pointer = (int *)realloc(array->array, array->size * sizeof(int));

    if (int_pointer == NULL)
    {       
        printf("Unable to reallocate memory, exiting.\n");
        free(int_pointer);
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        array->array = int_pointer;
        array->array[array->size-1] = item;
    }
}

/* Delete from a dynamic array */
void Array_Delete(Array *array, int index) 
{
    int i;
    Array temp;
    int *int_pointer;

    Array_Init(&temp);

    for(i=index; i<array->size; i++)
    {
        array->array[i] = array->array[i + 1];
    }

    array->size -= 1;

    for (i = 0; i < array->size; i++)
    {
        Array_Add(&temp, array->array[i]);
    }

    int_pointer = (int *)realloc(temp.array, temp.size * sizeof(int));

    if (int_pointer == NULL)
    {       
        printf("Unable to reallocate memory, exiting.\n");
        free(int_pointer);
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        array->array = int_pointer; 
    } 
}

/* Free an array */
void Array_Free(Array *array) 
{
  free(array->array);
  array->array = NULL;
  array->size = 0;  
}
```

The main.c looks like this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "storage.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    Array pointers;
    int i;

    Array_Init(&pointers);

    for (i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        Array_Add(&pointers, i);        
    }

    Array_Delete(&pointers, 3);

    Array_Delete(&pointers, 6);

    Array_Delete(&pointers, 30);

    for (i = 0; i < pointers.size; i++)
    {        
        printf("Value: %d Size:%d \n", pointers.array[i], pointers.size);
    }

    Array_Free(&pointers);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Look forward to the **constructive criticism** to follow...

Comment: If it is constructive criticism that you seek, better to post over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). That said, a couple of suggestions: it is imperative that code checks for success of calls to `malloc()` before attempting to use the allocation. In the same vein, it is a mistake to directly assign the result of `realloc()` to the pointer to the original memory being reallocated; if `realloc()` fails, `NULL` is returned, and code is left with a memory leak. It is much more efficient to double memory when resizing than to add 1 space at a time: fewer calls to `realloc()`.

Comment: I knew I was going to get ripped apart, I was just joking when I said "constructive criticism"...Thanks for the advice...

Comment: Not trying to rip anyone apart, just offering some constructive criticism, which may have been forthcoming even without your light-hearted closer ;)

Comment: David, I've been thinking about your comment "It is much more efficient to double memory when resizing than to add 1 space at a time: fewer calls to realloc()". Would you elaborate on that for me please, why is it better to allocate double the amount of memory and possibly not use it, therefore wasting memory, than assigning just the amount required for the task? I get what you're saying about calls to realloc(), but why is calling realloc() every time an issue? Is that not what it is there for, to reallocate memory?

Comment: If you take these conversation into consideration [here](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/FBVector.md#memory-handling) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727136/performance-impact-of-realloc). They say that "it can be mathematically proven that a growth factor of 2 is rigorously the worst possible because it never allows the vector to reuse any of its previously-allocated memory".

Comment: @David Bowling, I've also updated my code to take into consideration your remarks...

Comment: While strict doubling may not be optimal, it is certainly better than increasing memory one byte (or one `int`, etc.) at a time. Doubling is a typical solution, but I don't think that there is any optimal solution that fits all circumstances. Here is why doubling is a good idea (some other factor such as 1.5 would be fine as well): if you begin with a reasonable allocation, you may not need to reallocate at all. When more memory is needed, the reasonable allocation is doubled, and so on. In this way you likely need only one or two calls to `realloc()`.

Comment: For a large array, that might be one or two calls to `realloc()` vs. many thousands of calls to `realloc()`. Trim the allocation to final size with a final call to `realloc()`, and no excess memory is wasted.

Comment: I see that the result of `realloc()` is still being directly assigned to the original pointer. If `realloc()` fails, a `NULL` pointer is returned and would be so assigned. In this case, there would no longer be a pointer to the original memory (which has not been and can no longer be deallocated: memory leak). The right way to do this is: `int *temp = realloc(/* ... */);  if temp == NULL {/* handle error */ } else { int_pointer = temp; }`. Also, no need to cast `malloc()` and friends. Consider `int_pointer = malloc(sizeof *int_pointer);`: idiomatic, less error-prone, maintainable.

Comment: The reason we tend to double rather than linearly scale is because the bookkeeping (both time and memory) of realloc is typically a bottleneck; the less calls to it you make, the less bookkeeping and fragmentation it causes, the better. Also, allocation typically starts by allocating a whole page of memory to the process, so you're mistaken if you think this is "only using what's required" then you've probably not familiarised yourself with the facts.

Answer (score 2):

When you're saying

> make an array holding an index number (int) of an indeterminate number of entities

you're basically saying you're using "pointers", but one which is a array-wide local pointer instead of memory-wide pointer. Since you're conceptually already using "pointers" (i.e. id numbers that refers to an element in an array), why don't you just use regular pointers (i.e. id numbers that refers to an element in the biggest array: the whole memory).

Instead of your objects storing a resource id numbers, you can make them store a pointer instead. Basically the same thing, but much more efficient since we avoid turning "array + index" into a "pointer".

Pointers are not scary if you think of them as array index for the whole memory (which is what they actually are)

Answer (score 1):

To create an array of unlimited items of any sort of type:

```
typedef struct STRUCT_SS_VECTOR {
    size_t size;
    void** items;
} ss_vector;


ss_vector* ss_init_vector(size_t item_size) {
    ss_vector* vector;
    vector = malloc(sizeof(ss_vector));
    vector->size = 0;
    vector->items = calloc(0, item_size);

    return vector;
}

void ss_vector_append(ss_vector* vec, void* item) {
    vec->size++;
    vec->items = realloc(vec->items, vec->size * sizeof(item));
    vec->items[vec->size - 1] = item;
};

void ss_vector_free(ss_vector* vec) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vec->size; i++)
        free(vec->items[i]);

    free(vec->items);
    free(vec);
}
```

and how to use it:

```
// defining some sort of struct, can be anything really
typedef struct APPLE_STRUCT {
    int id;
} apple;

apple* init_apple(int id) {
    apple* a;
    a = malloc(sizeof(apple));
    a-> id = id;
    return a;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ss_vector* vector = ss_init_vector(sizeof(apple));

    // inserting some items
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        ss_vector_append(vector, init_apple(i));


    // dont forget to free it
    ss_vector_free(vector);

    return 0;
}
```

This vector/array can hold any type of item and it is completely dynamic in size.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess if you need to remove an element you will make a copy of the array despising the element to be excluded.

```
// inserting some items
void* element_2_remove = getElement2BRemove();

for (int i = 0; i < vector->size; i++){
       if(vector[i]!=element_2_remove) copy2TempVector(vector[i]);
       }

free(vector->items);
free(vector);
fillFromTempVector(vector);
//
```

Assume that `getElement2BRemove()`, `copy2TempVector( void* ...)` and `fillFromTempVector(...)` are auxiliary methods to handle the temp vector.

Comment: It's unclear if this is actually an answer to the question posed, or if it a comment.

Comment: It's an opinion for "how to" and I am asking for confirmation (Am I wrong?) IF someone has a better idea. ;)

Comment: I guess I don't understand your last sentence. Since SO is not a threaded forum, open questions like this in answers look odd.

Comment: I fixed up your last sentence to what I think you want to say.

Answer (score 0):

These posts apparently are in the wrong order! This is #1 in a series of 3 posts. Sorry.

In attempting to use Lie Ryan's code, I had problems retrieving stored information. The vector's elements are not stored contiguously,as you can see by "cheating" a bit and storing the pointer to each element's address (which of course defeats the purpose of the dynamic array concept) and examining them.

With a bit of tinkering, via:

```
ss_vector* vector; // pull this out to be a global vector

// Then add the following to attempt to recover stored values.

int return_id_value(int i,apple* aa) // given ptr to component,return data item
{   printf("showing apple[%i].id = %i and  other_id=%i\n",i,aa->id,aa->other_id);
    return(aa->id);
}

int Test(void)  // Used to be "main" in the example
{   apple* aa[10]; // stored array element addresses
    vector = ss_init_vector(sizeof(apple));
    // inserting some items
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {   aa[i]=init_apple(i);
        printf("apple id=%i and  other_id=%i\n",aa[i]->id,aa[i]->other_id);
        ss_vector_append(vector, aa[i]);
     }   
 // report the number of components
 printf("nmbr of components in vector = %i\n",(int)vector->size);
 printf(".*.*array access.*.component[5] = %i\n",return_id_value(5,aa[5]));
 printf("components of size %i\n",(int)sizeof(apple));
 printf("\n....pointer initial access...component[0] = %i\n",return_id_value(0,(apple *)&vector[0]));
 //.............etc..., followed by
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {   printf("apple[%i].id = %i at address %i, delta=%i\n",i,    return_id_value(i,aa[i]) ,(int)aa[i],(int)(aa[i]-aa[i+1]));
 }   
// don't forget to free it
ss_vector_free(vector);
return 0;
}
```

It's possible to access each array element without problems, as long as you know its address, so I guess I'll try adding a "next" element and use this as a linked list. Surely there are better options, though. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

These posts may be in the wrong order! This is #2 in a series of 3 posts. Sorry.

I've "taken a few liberties" with Lie Ryan's code, implementing a linked list so individual elements of his vector can be accessed via a linked list. This allows access, but admittedly it is time-consuming to access individual elements due to search overhead, i.e. walking down the list until you find the right element. I'll cure this by maintaining an address vector containing subscripts 0 through whatever paired with memory addresses. This is still not as efficient as a plain-and-simple array would be, but at least you don't have to "walk the list" searching for the proper item.

```
    // Based on code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536153/c-dynamically-growing-array
typedef struct STRUCT_SS_VECTOR
{   size_t size; // # of vector elements
    void** items; // makes up one vector element's component contents
    int subscript; // this element's subscript nmbr, 0 thru whatever
    struct STRUCT_SS_VECTOR* this_element; // linked list via this ptr
    struct STRUCT_SS_VECTOR* next_element; // and next ptr
} ss_vector;

ss_vector* vector; // ptr to vector of components

ss_vector* ss_init_vector(size_t item_size) // item_size is size of one array member
{   vector= malloc(sizeof(ss_vector)); 
    vector->this_element = vector; 
    vector->size = 0; // initialize count of vector component elements
    vector->items = calloc(1, item_size); // allocate & zero out memory for one linked list element
    vector->subscript=0;
    vector->next_element=NULL;
    //      If there's an array of element addresses/subscripts, install it now.
    return vector->this_element;
}

ss_vector* ss_vector_append(ss_vector* vec_element,                 int i) 
//                                                                          ^--ptr to this element  ^--element nmbr
{   ss_vector* local_vec_element=0;
    // If there is already a next element, recurse to end-of-linked-list
    if(vec_element->next_element!=(size_t)0) 
    {   local_vec_element= ss_vector_append(vec_element->next_element,i); // recurse to end of list
        return local_vec_element;
    }
    // vec_element is NULL, so make a new element and add at end of list
    local_vec_element= calloc(1,sizeof(ss_vector)); // memory for one component
    local_vec_element->this_element=local_vec_element; // save the address
    local_vec_element->next_element=0;
    vec_element->next_element=local_vec_element->this_element;
    local_vec_element->subscript=i; //vec_element->size; 
    local_vec_element->size=i; // increment # of vector components
    //      If there's an array of element addresses/subscripts, update it now.
    return local_vec_element;
}

void ss_vector_free_one_element(int i,gboolean Update_subscripts) 
{   // Walk the entire linked list to the specified element, patch up 
    //      the element ptrs before/next, then free its contents, then free it.
    //      Walk the rest of the list, updating subscripts, if requested.
    //      If there's an array of element addresses/subscripts, shift it along the way.
    ss_vector* vec_element;
    struct STRUCT_SS_VECTOR* this_one;
    struct STRUCT_SS_VECTOR* next_one;
    vec_element=vector;
    while((vec_element->this_element->subscript!=i)&&(vec_element->next_element!=(size_t) 0)) // skip
    {   this_one=vec_element->this_element; // trailing ptr
        next_one=vec_element->next_element; // will become current ptr
        vec_element=next_one;
    } 
    // now at either target element or end-of-list
    if(vec_element->this_element->subscript!=i)
    {   printf("vector element not found\n");return;}
    // free this one
    this_one->next_element=next_one->next_element;// previous element points to element after current one
    printf("freeing element[%i] at %lu",next_one->subscript,(size_t)next_one);
    printf(" between %lu and %lu\n",(size_t)this_one,(size_t)next_one->next_element);
    vec_element=next_one->next_element; 
    free(next_one); // free the current element
    // renumber if requested
    if(Update_subscripts)
    {   i=0;
        vec_element=vector;
        while(vec_element!=(size_t) 0)
        {   vec_element->subscript=i;
            i++;
            vec_element=vec_element->next_element; 
        }
    }
    //      If there's an array of element addresses/subscripts, update it now.
/*  // Check: temporarily show the new list
    vec_element=vector;
    while(vec_element!=(size_t) 0)
    {   printf("   remaining element[%i] at %lu\n",vec_element->subscript,(size_t)vec_element->this_element);
        vec_element=vec_element->next_element;
    } */
    return;
} // void ss_vector_free_one_element()

void ss_vector_insert_one_element(ss_vector* vec_element,int place) 
{   // Walk the entire linked list to specified element "place", patch up 
    //      the element ptrs before/next, then calloc an element and store its contents at "place".
    //      Increment all the following subscripts.
    //      If there's an array of element addresses/subscripts, make a bigger one, 
    //      copy the old one, then shift appropriate members.
    // ***Not yet implemented***
} // void ss_vector_insert_one_element()

void ss_vector_free_all_elements(void) 
{   // Start at "vector".Walk the entire linked list, free each element's contents, 
    //      free that element, then move to the next one.
    //      If there's an array of element addresses/subscripts, free it.
    ss_vector* vec_element;
    struct STRUCT_SS_VECTOR* next_one;
    vec_element=vector;
    while(vec_element->next_element!=(size_t) 0)
    {   next_one=vec_element->next_element;
        // free(vec_element->items) // don't forget to free these
        free(vec_element->this_element);
        vec_element=next_one;
        next_one=vec_element->this_element;
    }
    // get rid of the last one.
    // free(vec_element->items)
    free(vec_element);
    vector=NULL;
    //      If there's an array of element addresses/subscripts, free it now.
printf("\nall vector elements & contents freed\n");
} // void ss_vector_free_all_elements()

// defining some sort of struct, can be anything really
typedef struct APPLE_STRUCT
{   int id; // one of the data in the component
    int other_id; // etc
    struct APPLE_STRUCT* next_element;
} apple; // description of component

apple* init_apple(int id) // make a single component
{   apple* a; // ptr to component
    a = malloc(sizeof(apple)); // memory for one component
    a->id = id; // populate with data
    a->other_id=id+10;
    a->next_element=NULL;
    // don't mess with aa->last_rec here
    return a; // return pointer to component
};

int return_id_value(int i,apple* aa) // given ptr to component, return single data item
{   printf("was inserted as apple[%i].id = %i     ",i,aa->id);
    return(aa->id);
}

ss_vector* return_address_given_subscript(ss_vector* vec_element,int i) 
// always make the first call to this subroutine with global vbl "vector"
{   ss_vector* local_vec_element=0;
    // If there is a next element, recurse toward end-of-linked-list
    if(vec_element->next_element!=(size_t)0)
    {   if((vec_element->this_element->subscript==i))
        {   return vec_element->this_element;}
        local_vec_element= return_address_given_subscript(vec_element->next_element,i); // recurse to end of list
        return local_vec_element;
    }
    else
    {   if((vec_element->this_element->subscript==i)) // last element
        {   return vec_element->this_element;}
        // otherwise, none match
        printf("reached end of list without match\n");
        return (size_t) 0;
    }
} // return_address_given_subscript()

int Test(void)  // was "main" in the original example
{   ss_vector* local_vector;
    local_vector=ss_init_vector(sizeof(apple)); // element "0"
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) // inserting items "1" thru whatever
    {   local_vector=ss_vector_append(vector,i);}   
    // test search function
    printf("\n NEXT, test search for address given subscript\n");
    local_vector=return_address_given_subscript(vector,5);
    printf("finished return_address_given_subscript(5) with vector at %lu\n",(size_t)local_vector);
    local_vector=return_address_given_subscript(vector,0);
    printf("finished return_address_given_subscript(0) with vector at %lu\n",(size_t)local_vector);
    local_vector=return_address_given_subscript(vector,9);
    printf("finished return_address_given_subscript(9) with vector at %lu\n",(size_t)local_vector);
    // test single-element removal
    printf("\nNEXT, test single element removal\n");
    ss_vector_free_one_element(5,FALSE); // without renumbering subscripts
    ss_vector_free_one_element(3,TRUE);// WITH renumbering subscripts
    // ---end of program---
    // don't forget to free everything
    ss_vector_free_all_elements(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These posts apparently are in the wrong order! This is #3 in a series of 3 posts. Sorry.

I've "taken a few MORE liberties" with Lie Ryan's code. The linked list admittedly was time-consuming to access individual
elements due to search overhead, i.e. walking down the list until you find the right element. I have now cured this by
maintaining an address vector containing subscripts 0 through whatever paired with memory addresses. This works
because the address vector is allocated all-at-once, thus contiguous in memory. Since the linked-list is no longer required,
I've ripped out its associated code and structure.

This approach is not quite as efficient as a plain-and-simple static array would be, but at least you don't have to "walk the list"
searching for the proper item. You can now access the elements by using a subscript. To enable this, I have had
to add code to handle cases where elements are removed and the "actual" subscripts wouldn't be reflected in the
pointer vector's subscripts. This may or may not be important to users. For me, it IS important, so
I've made re-numbering of subscripts optional. If renumbering is not used, program flow goes to a dummy
"missing" element which returns an error code, which users can choose to ignore or to act on as required.

From here, I'd advise users to code the "elements" portion to fit their needs and make sure that it runs correctly. If your
added elements are arrays, carefully code subroutines to access them, seeing as how there's extra array structure
that wasn't needed with static arrays. Enjoy!

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


// Code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536153/c-dynamically-growing-array
// For pointer-to-pointer info see:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c-and-when-might-you-use-them
typedef struct STRUCT_SS_VECTOR
{   size_t size; // # of vector elements
    void** items; // makes up one vector element's component contents
    int subscript; // this element's subscript nmbr, 0 thru whatever
 //   struct STRUCT_SS_VECTOR* this_element; // linked list via this ptr
 //   struct STRUCT_SS_VECTOR* next_element; // and next ptr
} ss_vector;

ss_vector* vector; // ptr to vector of components
ss_vector* missing_element(int subscript) // intercepts missing elements
{   printf("missing element at subscript %i\n",subscript);
    return NULL;
}

typedef struct TRACKER_VECTOR
{   int subscript;
    ss_vector* vector_ptr;
} tracker_vector;  // up to 20 or so, max suggested

tracker_vector* tracker;
int max_tracker=0; // max allowable # of elements in "tracker_vector"
int tracker_count=0; // current # of elements in "tracker_vector"
int tracker_increment=5; // # of elements to add at each expansion

void bump_tracker_vector(int new_tracker_count)
{   //init or lengthen tracker vector
    if(max_tracker==0) // not yet initialized
    { tracker=calloc(tracker_increment, sizeof(tracker_vector));
        max_tracker=tracker_increment;
printf("initialized %i-element tracker vector of size %lu at %lu\n",max_tracker,sizeof(tracker_vector),(size_t)tracker);
        tracker_count++;
        return;
    }
    else if (max_tracker<=tracker_count) // append to existing tracker vector by writing a new one, copying old one
    {   tracker_vector* temp_tracker=calloc(max_tracker+tracker_increment,sizeof(tracker_vector));  
        for(int i=0;(i<max_tracker);i++){   temp_tracker[i]=tracker[i];} // copy old tracker to new
        max_tracker=max_tracker+tracker_increment;
        free(tracker);
        tracker=temp_tracker;
printf("  re-initialized %i-element tracker vector of size %lu at %lu\n",max_tracker,sizeof(tracker_vector),(size_t)tracker);
        tracker_count++;
        return;
    } // else if
    // fall through for most "bumps"
    tracker_count++;
    return;
}  // bump_tracker_vector()

ss_vector* ss_init_vector(size_t item_size) // item_size is size of one array member
{   ss_vector* vector= malloc(sizeof(ss_vector)); 
    vector->size = 0; // initialize count of vector component elements
    vector->items = calloc(1, item_size); // allocate & zero out memory for one linked list element
    vector->subscript=0;
    bump_tracker_vector(0); // init/store the tracker vector
    tracker[0].subscript=0;
    tracker[0].vector_ptr=vector; 
    return vector; //->this_element;
} // ss_init_vector()

ss_vector* ss_vector_append( int i) // ptr to this element, element nmbr
{   ss_vector* local_vec_element=0;
    local_vec_element= calloc(1,sizeof(ss_vector)); // memory for one component
    local_vec_element->subscript=i; //vec_element->size; 
    local_vec_element->size=i; // increment # of vector components
    bump_tracker_vector(i);  // increment/store tracker vector
    tracker[i].subscript=i;
    tracker[i].vector_ptr=local_vec_element; //->this_element;
    return local_vec_element;
}  // ss_vector_append()

void bubble_sort(void)
{   //  bubble sort
    struct TRACKER_VECTOR local_tracker;
    int i=0;
    while(i<tracker_count-1)
    {   if(tracker[i].subscript>tracker[i+1].subscript)
        {   local_tracker.subscript=tracker[i].subscript; // swap tracker elements
            local_tracker.vector_ptr=tracker[i].vector_ptr;
            tracker[i].subscript=tracker[i+1].subscript;
            tracker[i].vector_ptr=tracker[i+1].vector_ptr;
            tracker[i+1].subscript=local_tracker.subscript;
            tracker[i+1].vector_ptr=local_tracker.vector_ptr;
            if(i>0) i--; // step back and go again
        }
        else 
        {   if(i<tracker_count-1) i++;
        }
    } // while()
} // void bubble_sort()

void move_toward_zero(int target_subscript) // toward zero
{   struct TRACKER_VECTOR local_tracker;
    // Target to be moved must range from 1 to max_tracker
    if((target_subscript<1)||(target_subscript>tracker_count)) return; // outside range
    // swap target_subscript ptr and target_subscript-1 ptr
    local_tracker.vector_ptr=tracker[target_subscript].vector_ptr;
    tracker[target_subscript].vector_ptr=tracker[target_subscript-1].vector_ptr;
    tracker[target_subscript-1].vector_ptr=local_tracker.vector_ptr;
}

void renumber_all_subscripts(gboolean arbitrary)
{   // assumes tracker_count has been fixed and tracker[tracker_count+1]has been zeroed out
    if(arbitrary)  // arbitrary renumber, ignoring "true" subscripts
    {   for(int i=0;i<tracker_count;i++) 
        {   tracker[i].subscript=i;}
    }
    else // use "true" subscripts, holes and all
    {   for(int i=0;i<tracker_count;i++) 
        {   if ((size_t)tracker[i].vector_ptr!=0) // renumbering "true" subscript tracker & vector_element
            {   tracker[i].subscript=tracker[i].vector_ptr->subscript;}
            else // renumbering "true" subscript tracker & NULL vector_element
            {   tracker[i].subscript=-1;}
        } // for()
        bubble_sort(); 
    } // if(arbitrary) ELSE
} // renumber_all_subscripts()

void collapse_tracker_higher_elements(int target_subscript)
{   // Fix tracker vector by collapsing higher subscripts toward 0.
    //  Assumes last tracker element entry is discarded.
    int j;
    for(j=target_subscript;(j<tracker_count-1);j++)
    {   tracker[j].subscript=tracker[j+1].subscript;
        tracker[j].vector_ptr=tracker[j+1].vector_ptr;
    }
    // Discard last tracker element and adjust count
    tracker_count--;
    tracker[tracker_count].subscript=0;
    tracker[tracker_count].vector_ptr=(size_t)0;
} // void collapse_tracker_higher_elements()

void ss_vector_free_one_element(int target_subscript, gboolean Keep_subscripts) 
{   // Free requested element contents.
    //      Adjust subscripts if desired; otherwise, mark NULL.
    // ----special case: vector[0]
    if(target_subscript==0) // knock out zeroth element no matter what
    {   free(tracker[0].vector_ptr);} 
    // ----if not zeroth, start looking at other elements
    else if(tracker_count<target_subscript-1)
    {   printf("vector element not found\n");return;}
    // Requested subscript okay. Freeit. 
    else
    {   free(tracker[target_subscript].vector_ptr);} // free element ptr
    // done with removal.
    if(Keep_subscripts) // adjust subscripts if required.
    {   tracker[target_subscript].vector_ptr=missing_element(target_subscript);} // point to "0" vector
    else // NOT keeping subscripts intact, i.e. collapsing/renumbering all subscripts toward zero
    {   collapse_tracker_higher_elements(target_subscript);
        renumber_all_subscripts(TRUE); // gboolean arbitrary means as-is, FALSE means by "true" subscripts
    } // if (target_subscript==0) else
// show the new list
// for(int i=0;i<tracker_count;i++){printf("   remaining element[%i] at %lu\n",tracker[i].subscript,(size_t)tracker[i].vector_ptr);}
} // void ss_vector_free_one_element()

void ss_vector_free_all_elements(void) 
{   // Start at "tracker[0]". Walk the entire list, free each element's contents, 
    //      then free that element, then move to the next one.
    //      Then free the "tracker" vector.
    for(int i=tracker_count;i>=0;i--) 
    {   // Modify your code to free vector element "items" here
        if(tracker[i].subscript>=0) free(tracker[i].vector_ptr);
    }
    free(tracker);
    tracker_count=0;
} // void ss_vector_free_all_elements()

// defining some sort of struct, can be anything really
typedef struct APPLE_STRUCT
{   int id; // one of the data in the component
    int other_id; // etc
    struct APPLE_STRUCT* next_element;
} apple; // description of component

apple* init_apple(int id) // make a single component
{   apple* a; // ptr to component
    a = malloc(sizeof(apple)); // memory for one component
    a->id = id; // populate with data
    a->other_id=id+10;
    a->next_element=NULL;
    // don't mess with aa->last_rec here
    return a; // return pointer to component
}

int return_id_value(int i,apple* aa) // given ptr to component, return single data item
{   printf("was inserted as apple[%i].id = %i     ",i,aa->id);
    return(aa->id);
}

ss_vector* return_address_given_subscript(int i) 
{   return tracker[i].vector_ptr;} 

int Test(void)  // was "main" in the example
{   int i;
    ss_vector* local_vector;
    local_vector=ss_init_vector(sizeof(apple)); // element "0"
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) // inserting items "1" thru whatever
    {local_vector=ss_vector_append(i);}   // finished ss_vector_append()
    // list all tracker vector entries
    for(i=0;(i<tracker_count);i++) {printf("tracker element [%i] has address %lu\n",tracker[i].subscript, (size_t)tracker[i].vector_ptr);}
    // ---test search function
    printf("\n NEXT, test search for address given subscript\n");
    local_vector=return_address_given_subscript(5);
printf("finished return_address_given_subscript(5) with vector at %lu\n",(size_t)local_vector);
    local_vector=return_address_given_subscript(0);
printf("finished return_address_given_subscript(0) with vector at %lu\n",(size_t)local_vector);
    local_vector=return_address_given_subscript(9);
printf("finished return_address_given_subscript(9) with vector at %lu\n",(size_t)local_vector);
    // ---test single-element removal
    printf("\nNEXT, test single element removal\n");
    ss_vector_free_one_element(5,TRUE); // keep subscripts; install dummy error element
printf("finished ss_vector_free_one_element(5)\n");
    ss_vector_free_one_element(3,FALSE);
printf("finished ss_vector_free_one_element(3)\n");
    ss_vector_free_one_element(0,FALSE);
    // ---test moving elements
printf("\n Test moving a few elements up\n");
    move_toward_zero(5);
    move_toward_zero(4);
    move_toward_zero(3);
    // show the new list
    printf("New list:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<tracker_count;i++){printf("   %i:element[%i] at %lu\n",i,tracker[i].subscript,(size_t)tracker[i].vector_ptr);}
    // ---plant some bogus subscripts for the next subscript test
    tracker[3].vector_ptr->subscript=7;
    tracker[3].subscript=5;
    tracker[7].vector_ptr->subscript=17;
    tracker[3].subscript=55;
printf("\n RENUMBER to use \"actual\" subscripts\n");   
    renumber_all_subscripts(FALSE);
    printf("Sorted list:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<tracker_count;i++)
    {   if ((size_t)tracker[i].vector_ptr!=0)
        {   printf("   %i:element[%i] or [%i]at %lu\n",i,tracker[i].subscript,tracker[i].vector_ptr->subscript,(size_t)tracker[i].vector_ptr);
        }
        else 
        {   printf("   %i:element[%i] at 0\n",i,tracker[i].subscript);
        }
    }
printf("\nBubble sort to get TRUE order back\n");
    bubble_sort();
    printf("Sorted list:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<tracker_count;i++)
    {   if ((size_t)tracker[i].vector_ptr!=0)
        {printf("   %i:element[%i] or [%i]at %lu\n",i,tracker[i].subscript,tracker[i].vector_ptr->subscript,(size_t)tracker[i].vector_ptr);}
        else {printf("   %i:element[%i] at 0\n",i,tracker[i].subscript);}
    }
    // END TEST SECTION
    // don't forget to free everything
    ss_vector_free_all_elements(); 
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   char cmd[5],main_buffer[50]; // Intentionally big for "other" I/O purposes
    cmd[0]=32; // blank = ASCII 32
    //  while(cmd!="R"&&cmd!="W"  &&cmd!="E"        &&cmd!=" ") 
    while(cmd[0]!=82&&cmd[0]!=87&&cmd[0]!=69)//&&cmd[0]!=32) 
    {   memset(cmd, '\0', sizeof(cmd));
        memset(main_buffer, '\0', sizeof(main_buffer));
        // default back to the cmd loop
        cmd[0]=32; // blank = ASCII 32
        printf("REad, TEst, WRITe, EDIt, or EXIt? ");
        fscanf(stdin, "%s", main_buffer);
        strncpy(cmd,main_buffer,4);
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)cmd[i]=toupper(cmd[i]);
        cmd[4]='\0';
        printf("%s received\n ",cmd);
        // process top level commands
        if(cmd[0]==82) {printf("READ accepted\n");} //Read
        else if(cmd[0]==87) {printf("WRITe accepted\n");} // Write
        else if(cmd[0]==84) 
        {   printf("TESt accepted\n");// TESt
            Test();
        }
        else if(cmd[0]==69) // "E"
        {   if(cmd[1]==68) {printf("EDITing\n");} // eDit
            else if(cmd[1]==88) {printf("EXITing\n");exit(0);} // eXit
            else    printf("  unknown E command %c%c\n",cmd[0],cmd[1]);
        }
        else    printf("  unknown command\n");
        cmd[0]=32; // blank = ASCII 32
    } // while()
    // default back to the cmd loop
}   // main()
```