# Performance impact of realloc ()

Tags: c, algorithm, programming-languages

I have a list of records, at the starting I dont know the number of records. I need to read them into array. 
so is it advisable to read all record one by one & doing realloc one by one & go on increasing the array size as the element comes OR should I spend one pass in identifying the number of records & do malloc only once ? Which one will be be less computationally expensive ?

Comment: There is a middle ground. You can allocate a large chunk (I dunno, 100?) and if that fills up, realloc to 2x that size (or 1.5x or whatever makes sense). This is a common strategy for dynamic lists.

Comment: Implement both and measure... Is this in a time-critical section? Or is it just out of curiosity?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A `realloc` isn't really very expensive. But calling `realloc` for each element is a bit much. I suggest you do this:

- Start with a size
- When you add an element, check if you have enough space
- When you don't have enough space, double the currrent amount

Correctly guessing an adequate initial size also helps. So if 60% of your inputs are less than 100 records, start with that.

Comment: `realloc` may or may not be expensive to call since it takes linear time if the contents have to be moved. I have had to rewrite a program to precompute the output size because reallocation time was very significant, even when doubling the array size.

Comment: doubling is not neccesary to get linear performance, but you should always use a *constant* factor, increase by current size * K for some value K determined by experimentation that balances the cost of the realloc with the cost of wasted space.  For instance, the C++STL uses 1.5.  It's also possible to realloc downward to recover the unused memory once you're done adding to the array.

Comment: No approach is perfect. I myself have used a constant factor in the past (doubling the size proved problematic for large sizes). So I agree, other approaches might work better, depending on the application.

Comment: The important thing about using `realloc()` is _not to grow the chunk by constant amounts_ but _to grow it by relative amounts_, as @TokenMacGuy said. That way, the overhead remains linear in the size of the buffer. In more direct terms, `realloc()`'ing whenever you add to the container is a recipe for performance disasters.

Comment: re cnicutar: speculatively preallocating space when memory is in shortage is always doomed to failure.  Another option might be to build a linked list and then collect individual items into larger array chunks in a systematic manner, in effect trading bandwidth for space, based on which is more constrained.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy Awesome comment. I am beginning to feel I'm the one learning the most out of this question :-)

Answer (score 5):

It is a common technique to double the size of the array whenever it becomes full, as others have noted. In fact, using this technique ensures that no more than a constant amount of time is spent per element, as explained [on WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Geometric_expansion_and_amortized_cost).

Depending on how fast the code needs to be and what source you are reading from, it might be a good idea to compute the size of the output in a separate pass. If you are reading from disk you should probably use a dynamic array but otherwise you should probably do whatever is easier to implement.

Comment: "it can be mathematically proven that a growth factor of 2 is rigorously the worst possible because it never allows the vector to reuse any of its previously-allocated memory" -- https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/FBVector.md#memory-handling

Answer (score 0):

You should not `realloc( )` one-by-one.

The optimal strategy for this sort of thing depends on the specifics of what you're doing, but one common, simple, and nearly optimal approach is to increase your allocation size by a factor of two whenever you run out of room in your array.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using a linked list instead of an array for your task if it is possible. It will require only `malloc` to add new elements.