# Array sizes error in C

Tags: c, arrays

I wrote a program to do these tasks : First get a string from user and calculate the size of it with sizeof() function. Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char U1[];
    puts("Enter a string:");
    scanf("%s", U1);
    printf("The %s has %i bytes.", U1, sizeof(U1));
    return 0;
}
```

The compilation error is : `error: array size missing in ‘U1’`
Why ? Please explain what is wrong here ?

Comment: you need to allocate memory for char array.

Comment: It's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define array size to tell the compiler how much space to allocate:

```
char U1[256];
```

If you don't know the size of your array at compile time, you can dynamically allocate memory using `malloc`:

```
// #include <stdlib.h>
int *arr;
int n, i;
printf("Number of elements: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

// Allocate n ints
arr  = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

printf("Enter %d elements: ", n);
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

printf("Here they are: ");
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   printf("%d ", arr[i]);

// Free the array on the end!
free(arr);
```

**Note**

```
printf("The %s has %i bytes.", U1, sizeof(U1));
```

will always print 256, as `sizeof` returns the size of the array deducted at compile time, not the number of the characters just read into the array. You could use `sizeof(char) * (strlen(U1) + 1)` to compute number of bytes required by string (+1 comes from NUL-terminator character at the end of the string).

Answer (score 4):

C arrays are fixed-length, therefore every array needs to have its size fully specified when it is declared. A valid declaration is something like:

```
char U1[256];
```

Note that if the user enters more than that number of characters (minus one for the terminating zero), the behavior of that program is undefined. To avoid this problem, replace `scanf("%s")` with `fgets()` and learn about [dynamic arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536153/c-dynamically-growing-array).

Comment: No if you enter 257 byte string it will overflowed . Am I right ? How can I prevent that ?

Comment: @InJecTable Even if you enter a 256-byte string, it will overflow the array - because C strings are terminated with a null character. To avoid that, replace a single `scanf` with multiple calls to `fgets`, and use a dynamically allocated array, as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C needs to be declared with size.  The other option is to use dynamic arrays which are pointers

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a size to your array. Scanf takes an already allocated array and it do not resizes it, it just fill it with the input.

Your code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char U1[256];
    puts("Enter a string:");
    scanf("%s", U1);
    printf("The %s has %i bytes.", U1, strlen(U1));
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that I did not use `sizeof`, because I would have the entire size of the array, not just the string. `strlen` will give you the size of a C null-terminated string.

Comment: Right, if you want to count the last null byte, you need to add one.

Answer (score 0):

you should make a certain array, normal C compile do not support the dynamic array.