# Why can't I realloc this string?

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, null-terminated

I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct TEXT {
    char *text;
    struct TEXT *next;
} TEXT;
```

and in some function I have something like:

```
TEXT *line = (TEXT *) malloc(sizeof(TEXT));
line->text = NULL; // was "\0" before
char current = getchar();
while (current != '\n') {
    AddChar(&(line->text), current); // Was AddChar(line->text, current);
    current = getchar();
}
```

and the AddChar function was something like this:

```
void AddChar(char **text, char c) { //was char *text
    *text = (char *) realloc(*text, strlen(*text)+2); //was text = ...
    char char_array[2] = {c, '\0'); 
    strcat(*text, char_array); //was strcat(text, char_array);
}
```

And unfortunately, program crashed.

As far as I understand, turns out that strlen can't figure out that if text == NULL, length should be 0...

Anyway, with this AddChar function, everything works:

```
void AddChar(char **text, char c) {
    if (*text == NULL) {
        *text = (char *) malloc(2);
        (*text)[0] = c;
        (*text)[1] = '\0';
    }
    else {
        *text= (char *) realloc(*text, sizeof(*text)+2);
        char char_array[2] = { c , '\0' };
        strcat(*text, char_array);
    }
}
```

.

.

I also had a problem with

```
void AddChar(char *text, char c) {
    text = "something";
}
```

not changing line->text, but changing *text to **text fixed that.

Comment: Because you can't realloc a string literal.

Comment: `struct TEXT next;` isn't a valid field. Did you mean for it to be a pointer?

Comment: @Cornstalks yep, I did

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: You changed the code in the question *after* two answers were posted based on the original code. Is the program still misbehaving, or did the change fix it? (If the latter, that's a bad idea; fixing the code in the question invalidates the question).

Comment: In your alternate `AddChar` function, `text = "something";` just updates the parameter, which is a local variable. It has no effect on the value that was passed into the function.

Comment: @KeithThompson I had changed the program a little, all the changes are commented, unfortunately the main problem remains.

Comment: Don't add "[solved]" to the title.  To indicate that your problem has been solved, accept an answer. If none of the existing answers, solved your problem, you can post and accept your own answer.

Comment: `strlen()` on a null pointer has undefined behavior. It doesn't return 0 because there's no string.

Comment: Note that `getchar()` returns an `int` and you need to test for EOF as well as `'\n'`.

Answer (score 5):

Only a `NULL` initialized pointer or a pointer returned by `malloc` family functions (`malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc`) can be passed to another `malloc` family functions. `line->text` is initialized with a string literal `"\0"` and therefore `line->text` can't be passed to `realloc` function.
Also note that you can't modify a string literal.

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems is that you try to reallocate something you didn't allocate yourself.

The other problem is that you try to reassign a local variable inside the `AddChar` function and expect it to have any effect on the calling function, which it doesn't.

When passing an argument to a function it's passed *by value* which means that the value is copied into the local argument variable in the function, that variables local inside the function only, and changing that will not change the original variable used when calling the function. What you need is passing the argument *by reference* which C does not support, but you can *emulate* it by using a pointer. In your case by using a pointer to the pointer using the address-of operator `&`.

Comment: I thought I'm only passing a pointer (char*), not copying the whole string

Comment: @Jecke When you pass a pointer like you do, the *pointer* is copied. That leads you to have *two* pointer variables, initially pointing to the same memory, but once you reassign inside the function you have two different pointers each pointing to different locations.

Comment: I see. But why does pointer change after realloc? In this example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm the adress of str is same before and after realloc.

Comment: @Jecke The `realloc` function *may* return the same pointer. Or it *may* return a totally different pointer. Or it *may* return `NULL` (which you do not handle, and I don't mean you should just check for it, don't assign the result directly to the pointer you're reallocating as that might mean you loose the original pointer if `realloc` fails).

Comment: Ok, I see. I used char **text and &(line->text) and it works better now (if I write explicitly *text = "something", it changes), but I still can't handle realloc.

Comment: I have problem with strlen function. I have: 
`void AddChar(char **text, char c) {
    /*...*/
    strlen(*text);
    /*...*/
}` and it crashes when text is (null)

Comment: @Jecke Don't use `NULL` pointers when calling just about any function, using a null pointer leads to *undefined behavior* (and most likely crashes). Not all functions that accepts pointers are possible to call with a null pointer, only very few.

Comment: Oh, I'd think that the function returning length of null-terminated string will be able to tell the length of the null-terminated string. My bad; I broke it into two cases (text == NULL or not) and it works now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I understand, turns out that strlen can't figure out that if text == NULL, length should be 0...

On the other hand, [section 7.1.4, paragraph 1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4p1) the C standard states that NULL is an invalid value for `strlen`:

> **If an argument to a function has** an invalid value (such as a value outside the domain of the function, or a pointer outside the address space of the program, or **a null pointer**, or a pointer to non-modifiable storage when the corresponding parameter is not const-qualified) or a type (after promotion) not expected by a function with variable number of arguments, the behavior is undefined.

---

While we're on the subject of *invalid values*, `strcat` will expect that *both* of it's arguments contain strings. What this means is they must both contain a sequence of characters that terminates at the first `'\0'` character. You've demonstrated this by adding a `'\0'` character to the array representing your second argument, but can you prove that there's a `'\0'` character in the array representing your first argument?

---

> ```
> *text = (char *) realloc(*text, strlen(*text)+2);
> ```

Null pointer aside, anything of the pattern `x = realloc(x, ...);` is wrong. For more information on that, see [Proper usage of `realloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006707/proper-usage-of-realloc).

---

> ```
> *text= (char *) realloc(*text, sizeof(*text)+2);
> ```

As for this, it may seem to work for you at first, but I can assure you that it's broken. It is important to realise that you intend to allocate characters, not `char *`s, so `sizeof(*text)` (which is `sizeof (char *)`) is invalid here.

Typically this would allocate between 6 and 10 characters. If you overflow that buffer, the behaviour is undefined. What does that mean? Well, it'd be a paradox to define the undefined behaviour, but typical consequences of undefined behaviour range from "nothing at all" and "it works fine" for some systems to "segfaults" and "heartbleed" for other systems; it's not portable nonetheless.

---

> I also had a problem with
>
> ```
> void AddChar(char *text, char c) {
>     text = "something";
> }
> ```
>
> not changing line->text, but changing *text to **text fixed that.

I'm curious as to what you think `AddChar(NULL, 42);` would do, when `AddChar` is defined like this... Do you think it'd assign the null pointer constant that is `NULL` to the string literal that is `"something"`?

C doesn't support pass-by-reference. When you pass an argument (for example, a pointer, such as an array expressions implicitly converted to a pointer), what happens behind the scenes is a *new variable* is declared (in this case, the argument `char *text` is a variable) and a copy of that value (in this case, a pointer) is assigned to that variable. This is known as "pass-by-value".

When you pass a pointer, and modify the thing that the pointer is pointing at (e.g. by using `*pointer = ...` or `pointer[x] = ...`), you're emulating pass-by-reference; you're modifying an object that the variable refers to, rather than modifying the variable itself.

---

Ohh, and one more thing, despite the link to the "Proper usage of `realloc`", [you should not cast the return value of `malloc` (or `realloc) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 0):

Disagree with OP's final "Anyway, with this AddChar function, everything works:" as that does not allocate sufficient memory.

Suggest

```
void AddChar(char **text, char c) {
    size_t length = strlen(*text); 
    *text = realloc(*text, length + 2);  // proper size calculation
    if (*text == NULL) {  // check if successful
      abort(-1);
    } 
    (*text)[length] = c;
    (*text)[length + 1] = '\0';
}
```