# Using realloc to concat strings

Tags: c, arrays, realloc, strcat

I'm trying to concat two strings, supposing the "dest" string hasn't enough space to add another one, so I'm using dynamic arrays to solve it.

The problem is a **mremap_chunk** error when trying to compile the code.

I don't know what I'm missing since the realloc call has all the right params place in.

---

Error:

```
malloc.c:2869: mremap_chunk: Assertion `((size + offset) & (GLRO (dl_pagesize) - 1)) == 0' failed. 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *strcatt(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    int a = strlen(s1);
    int b = strlen(s2);
    int i, size_ab = a+b;

    s1 = (char *) realloc (s1, size_ab*sizeof(char));

    for(i=0; i<b; i++) {
        s1[i+a]=s2[i];
    }

    s1[size_ab]='\0';

    return s1;
}


int main()
{
    char s1[]="12345";
    char s2[]="qwerty";

    strcatt(s1,s2);
    printf("%s\n", s1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Replace `size_ab = a+b` with `size_ab = a+b+1`

Answer (score 4):

First, you are treating non-heap memory as heap memory, don't do that.

Second you're not including space for the terminator in the calculation.

Here are some more points:

1. Don't name functions starting with `str`, that's a reserved name space.
2. Buffer sizes should be `size_t`, not `int`.
3. [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).
4. Use `memcpy()` to copy blocks of memory when you know the size.
5. The "right hand side" strings should be `const`.
6. Deal with the possibility of allocation error.
7. I consider it bad practice to scale by `sizeof (char)`, that's always 1.

Here's how I would write it, assuming the same logic:

```c
char * my_strcatt(char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    const size_t a = strlen(s1);
    const size_t b = strlen(s2);
    const size_t size_ab = a + b + 1;

    s1 = realloc(s1, size_ab);

    memcpy(s1 + a, s2, b + 1);

    return s1;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the real problem reallocating an automatic array?

Comment: @MohitJain Heh. Yeah, for sure. I didn't make it to reading `main()`. Good catch!

Answer (score 3):

You can not `realloc` or `free` a memory that is not allocated with a call to `malloc` or is not `NULL`.

From section **7.22.3.5. The realloc function** in C11 draft

> The `realloc` function deallocates the old object pointed to by `ptr` and
>   returns a pointer to a new object that has the `size` specified by size.
>   The contents of the new object shall be the same as that of the old
>   object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of the new and old
>   sizes. Any bytes in the new object beyond the size of the old object
>   have indeterminate values.

So, `s1 = (char *) realloc (s1, size_ab*sizeof(char));` is plainly wrong for your inputs (automatic arrays), never do that.

And then there are many more problems which can be fixed with some help from a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

The *clang* debugger gives a very clear error description:

```
malloc:  error for object 0x7fff6fbb16d6: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
 set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Both of your arrays are initialized as string literals. Further on, your function tries to modify a string literal by reallocing it, which is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006707/proper-usage-of-realloc) by C standard because you can't reallocate what you haven't allocated, and then copying the members of the second string literal to the "object" you intended to modify by misusing `realloc()` on a string literal.

The code would work if you had *dynamically* defined a third string in which you would have summed the contents of both:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *mystrcatt(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    int a = strlen(s1);
    int b = strlen(s2);
    int i, size_ab = a+b;

    char *s3 = malloc (size_ab*sizeof(char)); //sizeof(char) is always 1

    for(i=0; i<a; i++) { //inefficient
        (s3[i])=s1[i];
    }    

    for(i=0; i<b; i++) { //inefficient
        (s3[i+a])=s2[i];
    }

    s3[size_ab]='\0';

    return s3;
}


int main()
{
    char s1[]="12345";
    char s2[]="qwerty";
    char *s3 = mystrcatt(s1,s2);    
    printf("%s\n", s3);
    free(s3);
    return 0;
}
```

Please, also note that you [don't cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc) the return of `malloc()` in C.

Comment: `gdb` is the debugger for `gcc`. What's the debugger for `clang`?

Comment: `lldb` is probably what you're asking for. Here's the [link](http://lldb.llvm.org). Thanks for your input.