# Reading from lines with strtok + qsort problem

Tags: c, file, realloc, strtok, qsort

What I wanted to create was a program that takes lines from an external file of the form `{key: value}`. For example, we have the file `t.dat`:

```
{myName: Mario}
{name2: Asdadas}
{someOtherData: _D123}
```

My program should have ordered this data in a decreasing manner based on the length of the `key` (in our case, `myName`, `name2`, or `someOtherData`) and if two keys with the same length are found, they should be ordered lexicographically based on the `value`.

I did this by using a `struct array` that will keep data for every line from the document:

```
typedef struct Line{
    char key[50];
    char value[50];
}Line;
```

and tried to take that data out from the file by using `fgets` (to take every line) and `strtok`.

This is my entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 512

typedef struct Line{
    char key[50];
    char value[50];
}Line;

int comp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const Line *aa = a;
    const Line *bb = b;
    puts(bb->key);
    if (strlen(aa->key) == strlen(bb->key)) {
        return strcmp(aa->key, bb->key);
    }
    return  strlen(bb->value)-strlen(aa->value);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid number of args.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!f)
    {
        printf("Unable to open the specified file.\n");
        return -2;
    }
    
    Line* ln;

    char buff[MAX];
    int lineNumber = 0;
    int isSet = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(buff, MAX, f))
    {
        char *p = strtok(buff, " {}:\n\r\t");
        while (p)
        {
            char word[MAX] = "";
            if (isSet == 0)
            {
                ln = malloc(1*sizeof(ln));
                isSet = 1;
            }
            else if (i == 0) ln = (Line*)realloc(ln, (lineNumber+1)*sizeof(ln));
            word[0] = '\0';
            if (i == 0) {
                strcpy(word, p);
                strcpy(ln[lineNumber].key, word);
                i = 1;
            }
            else if (i == 1) {
                strcpy(word, p);
                strcpy(ln[lineNumber].value, word);
                lineNumber++;
                i = 0;
            }
            p = strtok(NULL, " {}:\n\r\t");
        }

    }

    qsort(ln, lineNumber, sizeof(ln), comp);
    puts("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i<lineNumber; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", ln[i].key);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, the data from the first line isn't read correctly (I'm referring to `value` - `"Mario"`. It contains elements from the `key`, but certainly not the word `Mario`). Thought this may be from the `strtok`, but didn't find a solution for it.

Also, the data is not ordered properly using the provided `comp` function. It isn't ordered at all. The output is the same as it was before the order.

What can I do? Thank you. If any more details are needed, please tell me and I'll make sure I'll post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
ln = (Line*)realloc(ln, (lineNumber+1)*sizeof(ln));
```

you want to reserve spaces for n elements, not for n pointers to element, switch to

```
ln = realloc(ln, (lineNumber+1)*sizeof(*ln)); // Don't cast
```

also, [always use a temporary variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21006707/1606345) with `realloc`:

```
Line *temp = realloc(ln, (lineNumber+1)*sizeof(*ln));

if (temp == NULL)
{
    // raise error
}
ln = temp;
```

Same here

```
qsort(ln, lineNumber, sizeof(ln), comp);
```

each element occupies `sizeof(*ln)`, not `sizeof(ln)`, switch to

```
qsort(ln, lineNumber, sizeof(*ln), comp);
```

Comment: Modified the code, but lines are still unordered

Comment: Yes, `qsort` is also using the wrong size, you have an edit.

Comment: also, marked your reply as an answer. God bless you!!!