# Realloc crash: cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to malloc.exe.stackdump

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, string-concatenation, realloc, string-literals

I'm new with dynamic memory allocation and I tried to write a simple program to concatenate 2 strings (one initialized and one read from stdin) using realloc for the first string. But I receive this error:

cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to malloc.exe.stackdump

The code breaks at realloc and I do not know why, could you please help?

Input: man alive.

Expected output: The most beloved man alive.

I have tried replacing strlen with a number but with no avail.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "The most beloved";
    char str2[20];
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str2);
    //printf("%s %s\n", str, str2);

    str = (char *)realloc(str, strlen(str) + strlen(str2));

    strcat(str, str2);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);
}
```

Comment: You can only use `realloc` on memory previously allocated by `malloc`. Not on other memory which wasn't allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared a pointer to a string literal

```
char *str = "The most beloved";
```

String literals have static storage duration. So they may not be reallocated dynamically.

Thus this statement

```
str = (char *)realloc(str, strlen(str) + strlen(str2));
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Pay attention to that you need to reserve memory for the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the result string.

What you need is the following

```
char *result = ( char * )malloc( strlen(str) + strlen(str2) + 1 );

strcpy( result, str );
strcat( result, str2 );

puts( result );

free( result );
```

Also it would be more safer to write

```
scanf("%19[^\n]", str2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a pointer to `str` which was not allocated using `malloc`. You may pass pointers to `free` or `realloc` only if they have been allocated using `malloc`.

[Proper usage of realloc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006707/proper-usage-of-realloc)

You could do

```
str = strdup("mystring");
```

Also here you need to account for the `\0` at the end, so it should be:

```
str = (char *)realloc(str, strlen(str) + strlen(str2)+1);
```