# Is there any difference between allocating realloc() to a different pointer and allocating realloc() to the same one?

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

I´m kind of new to using dynamic memory in C and I was wondering if there was any diference between using realloc() to allocate to a different pointer and using realloc() to allocate the same pointer.
For example:

```
int *ptr = calloc(10,sizeof(int))
ptr=(int*)realloc(ptr,20);
```

and

```
*ptr3;
int *ptr = calloc(10,sizeof(int))
ptr3=(int*)realloc(ptr,20);
```

I´ve already executed both codes and I see no real diference between both codes (nor between the values of the opinters nor the memory allocations).
Thank you.

Comment: You'll have a memory leak in the first case if `realloc` fails

Comment: So the tag `c++` should be removed here? In `c++` code we almost never use calloc and realloc .

Answer (score 2):

The difference occurs in the former case when `realloc` fails; in that case, it returns `NULL`, but doesn't `free` the original `ptr` you passed it. By directly reassigning `ptr`, you guarantee a memory leak when `realloc` fails, because you no longer have the original pointer to `free`.

The canonical/correct usage seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21006798/364696) uses two pointers, one persistent, one as a temporary. The result of `realloc` is always put in the temporary so it can be checked (and the persistent pointer `free` on failure). After reallocation is known to have succeeded, the temporary pointer replaces the persistent (which is guaranteed to either be the same as the temporary, or if the allocation could not be done in place, invalid).

Answer (score 2):

For the first case, if `realloc` fails it returns a `null` pointer.
You would then be assigning that `null` pointer to `ptr` making it impossible to `free` the memory that was originally pointed to by `ptr`.

Instead, do something like below:

```
int* p = malloc( 10 * sizeof( int ) );

/* Take note of the memory size I'm requesting in the 
   realloc call compared to yours. */

int* tmp = NULL;
if ( ( tmp = realloc( p, 20 * sizeof( int ) ) ) == NULL ) {
    /* We failed to find available memory, but we're 
       still on the hook for freeing the memory pointed to by p. */

    free( p );
    return;
}

/* We were successful in either extending the memory pointed to by p
   or a new block of memory was allocated for us and the memory pointed to by p
   was copied over for us. In either case, you do not have to free p
   before assigning tmp to p. */

p = tmp;
```