# How Can I Know If This Program Works As i Intended( Dynamic stack )

Tags: c, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, function-definition

`enter code here`i was watching a video in data structures in C , and when i understand the abstract view of the concept i go try implementing it without watching the implementation in the video , and what i implement wasn't in the video, the video was affording stack(static array and linked list). so i thought maybe i try my own that is using (dynamic array), and the program did work but i'm still in doubt if it 100% work without any side effect .it's just that i can't believe the program works.
this program is intended to solve the overflow when pushing new value in the stack and without wasting memory space

(my doubts are : if it reallocate memory each time i push a new value correctly )

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int *ptr;
int top = -1;
int size = sizeof(int) ;

void Push(int x);
void Pop();
int Top();
char isEmpty();

int main(){

    Push(1);
    Push(2);
    printf("%d\n", *(ptr+top));
    Pop();
    printf("%d\n", *(ptr+top));
    printf("top = %d, is empty : %c", Top(), isEmpty());


    return 0;
}

void Push(int x){
    if(top == -1){
        ptr = (int* )malloc(size);
        *ptr = x;
        top++;
    }
    else{
        realloc(ptr, size * (top + 1));
        *(ptr+top+1) = x;
        top++;
    }

}

void Pop(){
    if(top == -1){
        return;
    }
    free(ptr+top);
    realloc(ptr, size * top - 1);
    top--;
}

int Top(){
    if(top != -1){
    return *(ptr+top);
    }
    printf("Empty Stack\n");
    return 0;
}

char isEmpty(){
    if(top == -1){
        return 'T';
    }
    return 'F';
}
```

Comment: "My doubts are : if it reallocate memory each time i push a new value correctly", and the answer to that is ***no***. There's no guarantee that the [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) function can reuse the existing memory, it might need to allocate new memory and copy the current contents to that new memory. Then just like `malloc` it *returns* the pointer to the new memory.

Comment: Also note that if `realloc` fails it will return a `NULL` pointer, but the original memory will be left remaining. So you should never reassign directly back to the pointer variable you use in the call. So `ptr = realloc(ptr, ...)` could lead you to lose the original and still valid memory.

Comment: How to use `realloc` : See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006707/proper-usage-of-realloc

Comment: OT: `isEmpty` is very unusual... Returning a character `T` or `F` for True/False is rather special (strange). If you don't want to use a bool type, the normal C way would be to return an `int` and use zero for False and a non-zero value (typically one) for True

Comment: @SupportUkraine it's not a big deal i just wanted to see if the function works or not , and you're right . maybe i can return an integer or bool ( and use if to print true or false)

Comment: This looks like something for [codereview.se]. And the [question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388112/620615) is terrible.

Comment: @user3840170 Sorry i'm new here , and this is my first question. And Thanks , i will keep in mind how to question properly and use Code Review

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program incorrectly manages memory.

For example in the function `Push` the address of the reallocated memory is lost

```
realloc(ptr, size * (top + 1));
```

So this statement

```
*(ptr+top+1) = x;
```

in general results in undefined behavior.

Moreover in this call of `realloc`

```
realloc(ptr, size * (top + 1));
```

the expression `(top + 1)` yields an incorrect number of allocated elements.

In the function `Pop` there is the same problem

```
realloc(ptr, size * top - 1);
```

and again the used expression `size * top - 1` within the function is invalid.

Also there is used an incorrect pointer expression to free memory

```
free(ptr+top);
```

You have to pass to the function free a pointer that was returned by allocation function `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.

The function `Top` does not check whether the stack is empty that again can invoke undefined behavior.

Pay attention to that it is not a good design when functions depend on global variables. It would be better to declare a structure that will specify properties of the stack. For example

```
struct Stack
{
    int *base;
    size_t top;
};
```

Then in `main` you could write

```
int main( void )
{
    Stack stack = { .base = NULL, .top = 0 };
    //...
```

The function `isEmpty` could look the following way

```
int isEmpty( const struct Stack *stack )
{
    return stack->top == 0;
}
```

and be called for example like

```
if ( isEmpty( &stack ) ) puts( "The stack is empty." );
```

The function `Push` could look the following way

```
int Push( struct Stack *stack, int item )
{
    int *tmp = realloc( stack->base, ( top + 1 ) * sizeof( *base ) );
    int success = tmp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        stack->base = tmp;
        stack->base[top++] = item;
    }

    return success;
}
```

The function `Top` can look like

```
int Top( const struct Stack *stack, int *item )
{
    if ( stack->top != 0 )
    {
        *item = stack->base[top - 1];
    }

    return stack->top != 0;
}
```

and be called like for example

```
int item;

if ( Top( &stack, &item ) )
{
    printf( "top = %d\n", item );
}
else
{
    puts( "The stack is empty." );
}
```