# Use of realloc correct approach

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I have the following line of code, which snippet correctly uses realloc?

I have a suspicioun that the realloc call in *delete_choices line is incorrectly used is this correct?

```
  *delete_choices = (char*)malloc(files_max);

 if (files_size >= files_max)
    {
        files_max *= 2;
        files = (struct dirent*)realloc(files, sizeof(struct dirent) * files_max);
        *delete_choices = (char*)realloc(delete_choices, files_max);
    }
```

Is this the correct usage?

```
*delete_choices = (char*)realloc(*delete_choices, files_max);
```

Really confused about this

Comment: You should use a temporary pointer to receive the result from `realloc`. If it fails and returns `NULL` you've lost the original pointer so you can't continue using the data you have or free the allocation to avoid a leak. [Proper usage of realloc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006707/proper-usage-of-realloc)

Comment: What exactly is your doubt about the usage? as `sizeof char` is defined to be 1, no need to use it to calculate the size. But in C, casting the return value of `malloc`, `realloc` etc. is not required and should be avoided as it can hide errors. Also assigning the return value directly to the initial pointer is a bad idea as Retired Ninja already mentioned.

Comment: The question cannot be answered unless you actually reveal the variable declarations.

Answer (score 3):

```
*delete_choices = (char*)malloc(files_max);

if (files_size >= files_max)
{
    files_max *= 2;
    files = (struct dirent*)realloc(files, sizeof (struct dirent) * files_max);
    *delete_choices = (char*)realloc(delete_choices, files_max);
}
```

The correct expression is:

```
*delete_choices = realloc (*delete_choices, files_max);
```

Furthermore, the above code snippet risks invoking undefined behaviour because if `realloc()` fails and returns a `NULL` pointer, you'd lose access to the original memory allocated through `malloc()` (assuming `malloc()` had succeeded), and leak memory.

**Solution:**

Use a temporary pointer to store the return value of `realloc()`:

```
/* Yes, the usage is correct. */
char *const tmp = realloc(*delete_choices, files_max);
if (!tmp) {
    perror("realloc()");
    complain();
}
      
*delete_choices = tmp;
```

Note: Do not cast the return of `malloc()` and family. These functions return a generic `void *` that is implicitly converted to any other pointer type. The cast is redundant and only serves to clutter one's code.

Comment: First and foremost is using the correct expression for the address for reallocation, `*delete_choices` in both places, not `delete_choices` in one and `*delete_choices` in another. Not using a cast is not first or foremost, because the incorrect expression is an actual bug (very important), whereas the cast is a code pattern used to reduce the occurrence of bugs (less important). This “answer” does not explicitly answer the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

`*delete_choices = (char*)realloc( *delete_choices, files_max );` is the correct usage.

The type that you pass must be equal to the type returned.

In your case, `delete_choices` appears to be of type `char**`, therefore `*delete_choices` is of type `char*`, so these two types are not equal.

In general: `t = (T)realloc( t, n );`