# C Expanding Integer Array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I am wondering on how to create an integer array in C which you can expand it by one index every time you need to store additional values. I came across malloc and realloc and sizeof, but I really don't know how they work. Can someone here give a brief example on how to accomplish this in C.

Comment: Please explain what it is you're ultimately trying to achieve. It may be that a linked-list or other data structure may be more suitable. Also, there are plenty of resources on the net to explain what malloc, et al, are and do.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536153/c-dynamically-growing-array. It describes what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize your array you may do this:

```
int* arr = malloc(n*sizeof(int)); // n is your initial required array size
// now you need more
int* temp = realloc(arr,another_size*sizeof(int));
// check if reallocation is successful
if(temp!=NULL)
    arr = temp;
```

---

Here's How malloc, realloc works:

[malloc man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)

 [realloc man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)

Comment: Note: In the corner case when `another_size == 0`, returning `NULL` may be a sign of success.  If `another_size == 0` is a possibility, better to use `if (temp != NULL || another_size == 0) arr = temp;`