# Having issues with scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I've been studying some C on my own and I was wondering if my segmentation fault is do to the way I'm trying to add *person to a dynamic array named students.
This originally started out as a method for me trying to learn how to use dynamic arrays but I got stumped with how I am failing to get around this scanf faulting my program. I included everything I've done, but I suspect my problem is within the main, specifically the scanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//ARR_LEN 
#define ARR_LEN 5
#define STR_LEN 15
//STUDENT STRUCT
typedef struct{
  int ID;
  char *name;
}Student;

typedef struct{
  Student *array;
  size_t used;
  size_t size;
}Array;

void initArray(Array *a, size_t initialSize){
  //ALLOCATING INITIAL SPACE
  a->array = (Student *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(Student));

  a->used = 0;
  a->size = initialSize;

  //INITIALIZES ALL VALUES OF THE ARRAY TO 0
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i<initialSize; i++){
    memset(&a->array[i],0,sizeof(Student));
  }
}

  //ADDING A STUDENT ELEMENT INTO ARRAY
void insertArray(Array *a,Student element){
  if(a->used == a->size){
    a->size *= 2;
    a->array = (Student *)realloc(a->array,a->size * sizeof(Student));
  }

//Copy Name
a->array[a->used].name = (char*)malloc(strlen(element.name) + 1);
strcpy(a->array[a->used].name, element.name);

//Copy ID
a->array[a->used].ID=element.ID;


a->used++;
}

void freeArray(Array *a){
 for(int i=0;i<a->used;i++){
    free(a->array[0].name);
    a->array[0].name=NULL;
 }

//Freeing the array
 free(a->array);
 a->array = NULL;

 a->used = 0;
 a->size = 0;
}




int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

char choice;
Array student;
Student *person;
char* firstName;
firstName = (char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
int* number;
 number = (int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
printf("Would you like to make a list of people? (y/n): ");
scanf("%c \n",&choice);
    while(choice == 'y'){
        initArray(&student, 5);
        printf("\nPlease enter students name: ");
        scanf("%s \n",&firstName);
                printf("NAME ENTERED: %s\n",firstName);
//      fgets(firstName,100,stdin);
        printf("\nPlease enter students ID: ");
        scanf("%i \n",number);
//      fgets(number,100,stdin);
                    for(int i = 0; i<ARR_LEN;i++){
                person->name = firstName;
                person->ID = (int)number;
                        insertArray(&student,*person);
                printf("Would you like to add another? (y/n): \n");
            }
    }   
printf("Would you like to print the list of people? (y/n): ");
scanf("%c \n",&choice);
    if(choice == 'y'){
        for(int x=0;x<sizeof(student);x++){
            printf("Name: %s", student.array[x].name);
        }       
    }
}
```

Now to give credit where its due. I grabbed the overall Dynamic Array scheme from "Casablanca" and was seeing if I could use it to overall understand how the Array was built. His/Her post can be found here: [C dynamically growing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536153/c-dynamically-growing-array)

Comment: you don't use `scanf("%c \n")` or something like this, just go `scanf("%c", &c)` and the rest are similar. note no space trailing. and another tip about `//Copy Name`, is to use `strdup`, which is one line call while does everything for you. then remember to check the return value of `malloc` and `realloc`, `strdup` as well.

Comment: `scanf("%s \n",&firstName)` shoule be `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",firstName)`.

Comment: Thanks, these three things cleared up everything. You guys are amazing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug is here:

```
void freeArray(Array *a){
    for(int i=0;i<a->used;i++){
        free(a->array[0].name);
        a->array[0].name=NULL;
    }
    ...
}
```

You repeatedly free the first element, but since you set it to `NULL`, subsequent calls to `free()` just do nothing.  The other element names never get freed.

Change this code to:

```
void freeArray(Array *a) {
    for(int i = 0; i < a->used; i++) {
        free(a->array[i].name);
        a->array[i].name = NULL;
    }
    ...
}
```

There is another problem here:

```
   scanf("%s \n",&firstName);
```

You do not limit the intput size.  This may cause a buffer overflow if the user enters a long name.  Use this instead:

```
   scanf("%99s \n",&firstName);
```

A more major bug here:

```
    Student *person;
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i<ARR_LEN;i++) {
        person->name = firstName;
        person->ID = (int)number;
        insertArray(&student,*person);
        ...
```

person should be a structure, not a pointer:

```
    Student person;
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i<ARR_LEN;i++) {
        person.name = firstName;
        person.ID = (int)number;
        insertArray(&student, person);
        ...
```

Another bad one here:

```
    for(int x=0;x<sizeof(student);x++){
        printf("Name: %s", student.array[x].name);
    }
```

You loop over `sizeof(student)` elements instead of `student.used`.

Use this instead:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < student.used; x++){
        printf("Name: %s\n", student.array[x].name);
    }
```

There many more problems in the code: for example, you do not handle out of memory conditions.