# C - Dynamic String Freeing and dynamic arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory-management

I have an issue that is related to my programming project this semester.
I have a dynamic array that has a structure, that structure contains a parameter for a string. The thing is I need to change that string from being static , to dynamic.
   I have written the function that asks for the string and stores it in a dynamic array and then returns it.
Later in the program I will need to write the info from the arrays (in which the dynamic string is stored) to a binary file.
How can I achieve this and how can I know when and how I am properly freeing the memory of that dynamic string?
If I free the array in which the string is stored, do I also free the memory in which the string itself is stored?

My array which will store the string:

```
inspections *inspectionsArray;


char* dynamicString(){
    char *stringPointer = NULL,*paux = NULL, char;
    int stringSize = 1,stringEnd = 0,i;
    stringPointer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)); 
    if (stringPointer == NULL) {
        printf("\nError alocating memory");
    }else{
        printf("\nEnter String: ");
        while (char != EOF && char != '\n') {
            char = getc(stdin); //Obter o char do stding
            paux = realloc(stringPointer, stringSize*sizeof(char));
            if (paux != NULL) {
                stringPointer = paux;
                stringPointer[stringEnd] = char; //meter o char na string
                stringSize++; //incrementar o tamanho da string
                stringEnd++;
            }else{
                printf("\nErro a realocar memoria para a string");
            }
        }
        stringPointer[stringEnd] = '\0';
        printf("\nString: %s", stringPointer);
    }
    return stringPointer;
}
```

The Structure in which I will have my string stored in.

```
typedef struct
{
    //A bunch of parameters in here
    char *dynamicString;

} inspection;


enter code here
```

Function I use to store data to array:

```
inspectionArray* registerInspection(inspection *inspectionArray){
    char *string;
    //I removed a bunch of code to not confuse things
    string = dynamicString;

    return inspection;
}
```

Function to save file:

```
void saveBinaryFile(inspection *inspections, int inspectionCounter)
{
    FILE * inspectionArrayFile;


    fileInspections = fopen("inspections.dat","wb"); 


    if (fileInspections == NULL)
    {
        perror("\nError opening the file");
    }
    else
    {
        fwrite(&inspectionCounter, sizeof (int), 1, inspectionArrayFile);
        fwrite(inspections, sizeof(tipoVeiculo), inspectionCounter, inspectionArrayFile);
        // I write a bunch of stuff and verify it properly
        fclose(inspectionArrayFile);

    }
}
```

How do I properly read and free the string ?

I tried this:

```
void freeArrayStrings(inspections *inspectionsArray,int counter){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<counter; i++) {
        free(inspectionArray[i].dynamicString);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Talk is cheap. Show me the code - Linus"

Comment: There are no dynamic arrays.

Comment: I have loads of code , I can't put it all here. Well, I'll try

Comment: You have at least two completely separate questions in there, one about output and one about memory management.  Ask *specific* questions here, and it is best if you support them with code.

Comment: Well, that's what we call them here. Static or Dynamic

Comment: I'll try to be more specific , sorry.

Comment: Will _[strdup()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa273370%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)_ work for you?  And _please_, no need for _all_ the code.  Just include the relevant parts needed to illustrate the problem you are trying to get help with.

Comment: @LuisValdez Try to create [mcve]

Comment: i think you need this: [c-dynamically-growing-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536153/c-dynamically-growing-array)

Comment: Do you mean dynamically allocated or really dynamic in the sense of changing size?

Comment: I apologize for not writing a good question. I have provided some translated code.

Comment: @Olaf I don't understand the difference. The string changes size according to the characters I type.

Comment: C does not have dynamically resizing arrays. And you use pointers, not an array (well, you have to). `realloc`ing for each character typed is a bad idea in general and very inefficient. You code has many faults&flaws. How does that even compile; you declare a variable with the same name as a built-in type(`char`). Also `getchar` returns an `int`, not a `char` for good reason! And don*t cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C (you do this inconsistently - general advice is never to cast if you do not fully understand all implications).

Comment: @Olaf , absolutely right. I didn't use char as a variable name, I was using the "caracter" which is char in portuguese. I translated it to char. I should use getc();

Comment: That change was contra-productive. I did not say not to use `getc`, but that it returns an `int` for a good reason. Please read the man pages of the functions you use and know their signatures. You cannot detect `EOF` reliable and portable with a `char` variable!

Comment: Getchar should work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have some specific reason for using *character-oriented* input for the `dynamicString()` function, you can greatly simplify your life by using one of the *line-oriented* input functions provided by the standard C library (e.g. `fgets` or `getline`). Also, in C, you traditionally you avoid the use of *camelCase* names and instead use *lower-case* for all variable and function names.

In the case of the `dynamicstring()` function, using `getline` your function reduces to:

```
char *dynamicstring (inspection *i)
{
    char *line = NULL;  /* buffer for input                 */
    size_t n = 0;       /* alloc size 0 - getline decides   */
    ssize_t len = 0;    /* no. of character read (or EOF)   */

    printf("\nEnter String: ");

    len = getline (&line, &n, stdin);   /* read input   */

    if (len <= 1) {  /* line contains only '\n', 0, EOF */
        free (line);
        return NULL;
    }

    while (len > 0 && line[len-1] == '\n') /* remove '\n'  */
        line[--len] = 0;

    i->dstring = line;    /* assign pointer to dstring  */

    return line;
}
```

(**note:** above i use `dstring` for your `char *dynamicString;` member)

You can refine the memory allocation size from the default allocated by `getline` to only that amount required for the input string by taking the length of the final `line`, allocating that amount of memory (+1 for the *nul-terminator*), and copying `line` to the new block of memory. You can do it all at once with the `strdup` function. For example, you could add the following to the function above and then return `str`:

```
    char *str = NULL;   /* pointer for final string storage */
    ...
    str = strdup (line);  /* refine allocation size     */
    free (line);

    i->dstring = str;     /* assign pointer to dstring  */

    return str;
```

Even with the refinement, the completed function is far simpler than your original. Now **note:** regardless whether you assign the return or not, since the function only returns an allocation if the input is not empty, there is a chance that some of your array of `inspection` string members will be allocated and some empty. Therefore, you will need to check before freeing the memory. e.g.:

```
    if (ia->dstring)
        free (ia->dstring);
```

As always, when allocating memory dynamically, use a memory error checker (like `valgrind` on Linux) to confirm the correct use and freeing of the memory you allocate. A short example of the use of this input function would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char *dstring;
} inspection;

char* dynamicstring (inspection *i);

int main (void) {

    inspection *ia= NULL;

    if (!(ia= malloc (sizeof *ia))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (dynamicstring (ia)) {
        printf ("\n inspectionArray->dynamicstring : %s\n\n", ia->dstring);
        if (ia->dstring)
            free (ia->dstring);
    }
    free (ia);

    return 0;
}

char *dynamicstring (inspection *i)
{
    char *str = NULL;   /* pointer for final string storage */
    char *line = NULL;  /* buffer for input                 */
    size_t n = 0;       /* alloc size 0 - getline decides   */
    ssize_t len = 0;    /* no. of character read (or EOF)   */

    printf("\nEnter String: ");

    len = getline (&line, &n, stdin);   /* read input   */

    if (len <= 1) {  /* line contains only '\n', 0, EOF */
        free (line);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* using shorthand 'len' instead of 'len > 0'
       both test false when 'len' is 0  */
    while (len && line[len-1] == '\n') /* remove '\n'  */
        line[--len] = 0;

    str = strdup (line);  /* refine allocation size     */
    free (line);

    i->dstring = str;     /* assign pointer to dstring  */

    return str;
}
```

Give it a try and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you David. That's exactly it!

Comment: Although some of the things you wrote are in C++. Are they not?

Comment: No, all of it is 100% pure C..... What parts looking like C++ to you? I'm happy to explain anything you have a question about. It is important you understand each line and each character in each line. There is no such thing as "*close-enough*" syntax...

Comment: On the dynamicString function ,you use a while , but you didn't use any brackets. Perhaps that could be done, I just never saw it. Thank you very much.

Comment: The `while (line && line[len-1] == '\n')` does need improvement to be correct. Good catch. It should be `while (len && line[len-1] == '\n')` which is just shorthand for `while (len > 0 && line[len-1] == '\n')`. This while you haven't worked backward all the way to the beginning and the last character is a `'\n'`, then overwrite the `'\n'` with a *nul-terminating* character `0` (equivalent to `'\0'`) but less typing) and substract `1` from `len` and check again. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should show your code in order to increase a chance of apt answer. If you ask about freeing of memory that stores pointers to another memory get from `malloc` like in this example:

```
struct str_wrap
{
    char *str;
    int  strlen;
};

int main()
{
    struct str_wrap *sw = malloc(sizeof *sw);
    if (sw == NULL) return -1;

    sw->str = malloc(strlen);
    if (sw->str == NULL)
        // handle
    sw->strlen = strlen;
    // many things with sw...
```

then yes, you have to call `free` twice (note: the same number of times you have called `malloc`):

```
    // free the memory
    free(sw->str);
    free(sw);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have an error: `stringPointer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` 
   You need `stringPointer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char *));` 
   sizeof(char) is probably 1 bytes; sizeof(char *) is probably 4.
   You might get away with it because some memory systems always allocate at least 32 bytes...
2. Don't realloc on every input character. Instead, declare char buf[255] or some other maximum size, keep a size index, assign your input char to the end, and then at the end do stringPointer = malloc(isize+1) and strcpy(stringPointer,buf); If you really might need a huge input buffer, start at 4K or 1M and then reallocate when you fill that space.

Comment: Won't that take up big amounts of memory though?

Comment: No - the idea is to have a single buffer allocated outside the getc loop. This will avoid a realloc call (which is relatively expensive) on every single character handled.