# Array of dynamic length

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *names = NULL;
    int capacity = 0;
    int size = 0;

    printf("Type 'end' if you want to stop inputting names\n");
    while (1) {
        char name[100];
        printf("Input:\n");
        fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);

        if (strncmp(name, "end", 3) == 0) {
            break;
        }

        if (size == capacity) {
            char *temp = realloc(names, sizeof(char) * (size + 1));

            if (!temp) {
                if (names) {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            names = temp;
            capacity++;
        }

        names[size] = name;
        size++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("OUTPUT :%c\n", names[i]);
    }

    if (names) {
        free(names);
    }
}
```

I am trying to create an array of dynamic length in C but I don't know what is wrong with my code? I think it is cause of how I take the user input and the problem occurs when the code `names[size] = name` is executed.

Comment: Indent your code properly. It's very hard to read

Comment: What if the user name is "endebbe"? :) Hint: the usual way to signal end of input is using the `EOF` signal.

Comment: You are messed up between `char *` and `char`. Example `names[size] = name;` `names` is also `char *` and `name` is also `char *`.

Comment: You should handle your dynamic array in functions ans not directly in `main`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C dynamically growing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536153/c-dynamically-growing-array)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare an array of pointers to strings (char**), not a pointer to a single character string (char*).

This means that when you want to add a new entry, not only do you need to make space for the new pointer in your array (type is `char*` not `char`) but you also have to separately allocate storage for the string itself and then set the pointer you just made space for to that allocated string.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- `names` should be defined as a pointer to an array of `char *`: `char **names = NULL;`
- you must make copies of the strings read with `fgets()`, otherwise all entries in `names` will point to the same array `name`.
- you actually do not need to distinguish `capacity` and `size` if you reallocate one extra slot at a time.
- the format `"OUTPUT :%c\n"` is incorrect for a string.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char **names = NULL;
    int capacity = 0;
    int size = 0;

    printf("Type 'end' if you want to stop inputting names\n");
    for (;;) {
        char name[100];
        printf("Input:\n");
        if (!fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin)) {
            break;
        }
        if (strncmp(name, "end", 3) == 0) {
            break;
        }
        if (size == capacity) {
            // reallocate array with geometric growth
            int new_capacity = capacity + (capacity / 2) + 4;
            char *temp = realloc(names, sizeof(*names) * new_capacity);
            if (!temp) {
                free(names);
                printf("out of memory\n");
                return 1;
            }
            names = temp;
            capacity = new_capacity;
        }
        name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the trailing newline if any
        names[size++] = strdup(name);      // allocate a copy of the string
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("OUTPUT: %s\n", names[i]);
    }
    free(names);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to compile it but there is 1 error               
 "<stdin>:25:19: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'char *' with an rvalue of type 'void *'
            char *temp = realloc(names, sizeof(*names) * new_capacity);" How do I solve it?

Comment: @drazer: you should compile the code as **c**, not **c++**. the gcc option is `-x c`.  Yo compile as c++, you need a cast: `char *temp = (char *)realloc(names, sizeof(*names) * new_capacity);`