# What is causing undefined behaviour in my use of realloc

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function that takes in position data, an array and a counter that stores number of elements in that array and populates that array with new position data and increments the counter. And since I need this array outside of the function, I'm dynamically allocating memory using `realloc`.

---

## Code

I have a `struct` to store co-ordinate data

```
typedef struct CoOrdinates
{
  int x;
  int y;

} CoOrdinates;
```

and a function that draws a box at any given position

```
void drawBox(WINDOW*       inWindow,
             int           aAtPositionX,
             int           aAtPositionY,
             int*          aOccupiedCoordinateCount,
             CoOrdinates** aOccupiedCoordinates)
{

  int    newCount       = (*aOccupiedCoordinateCount) + 1;
  size_t sizeResized    = sizeof(**aOccupiedCoordinates) * newCount;
  *aOccupiedCoordinates = realloc(*aOccupiedCoordinates, sizeResized);

  if (*aOccupiedCoordinates == NULL)
    {

      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate CoOrdinate array at %d in %s.", __LINE__, __FILE__);
      exit(-1);
    }
  else
    {
      (*aOccupiedCoordinates)[newCount].x = aAtPositionX;
      (*aOccupiedCoordinates)[newCount].y = aAtPositionY;

      *aOccupiedCoordinateCount = newCount;

      mvwprintw(inWindow, aAtPositionY, aAtPositionX, "██");
    }
}
```

where `mvwprintw` and `WINDOW*` are defined in [`ncurses`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

Another function is `drawTwoVerticleBoxes` defined like this

```
void drawTwoVerticleBoxes(WINDOW*       inWindow,
                          int           aAtPositionX,
                          int           aAtPositionY,
                          int*          aOccupiedCoordinateCount,
                          CoOrdinates** aOccupiedCoordinates)
{

  drawBox(inWindow, aAtPositionX, aAtPositionY, aOccupiedCoordinateCount, aOccupiedCoordinates);
  drawBox(inWindow, aAtPositionX, aAtPositionY + 1, aOccupiedCoordinateCount, aOccupiedCoordinates);
}
```

and a function called `drawWithColor`

```
void drawWithColor(WINDOW*       inWindow,
                   int           aAtPositionX,
                   int           aAtPositionY,
                   int*          aOccupiedCoordinateCount,
                   CoOrdinates** aOccupiedCoordinates)
{
  init_pair(1, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLACK);
  wattron(inWindow, COLOR_PAIR(1));

  drawTwoVerticleBoxes(
      inWindow, aAtPositionX, aAtPositionY, aOccupiedCoordinateCount, aOccupiedCoordinates);

  wattroff(inWindow, COLOR_PAIR(1));
```

Finally all of those are called in `renderRoutine`

```
void renderRoutine()
{

  ...
  ...

  int            occupiedCoordinateCount = 0;
  CoOrdinates*   occupiedCoordinates     = NULL;


  drawWithColor(windowPointer, 4, 4, &occupiedCoordinateCount, &occupiedCoordinates);

  wgetch(windowPointer);

  endwin();

  for (int i = 0; i < occupiedCoordinateCount; ++i)
    {
      printf("X: %d, Y: %d \n", occupiedCoordinates[i].x, occupiedCoordinates[i].y);
      free(occupiedCoordinates);
    }
}
```

---

## Summery

The idea is, every time a box is drawn, `occupiedCoordinates` will store `CoOrdinate` of that position. `occupiedCoordinateCount` will store how many items `occupiedCoordinates` have.

---

## Errors

### Expected results

```
X: 4, Y: 4
X: 4, Y: 5
```

### Actual results

```
X: 0, Y: 0
X: 504864784, Y: 22033

free(): double free detected in tcache 2
```

## Tweaks

If I define a function say `drawFiveHorizontalBoxes`

```
void drawThreeHorizontalBoxes(WINDOW*       inWindow,
                              int           aAtPositionX,
                              int           aAtPositionY,
                              int*          aOccupiedCoordinateCount,
                              CoOrdinates** aOccupiedCoordinates)
{

  drawBox(inWindow, aAtPositionX, aAtPositionY, aOccupiedCoordinateCount, aOccupiedCoordinates);
  drawBox(inWindow, aAtPositionX + 1, aAtPositionY, aOccupiedCoordinateCount, aOccupiedCoordinates);
  drawBox(inWindow, aAtPositionX + 2, aAtPositionY, aOccupiedCoordinateCount, aOccupiedCoordinates);
  drawBox(inWindow, aAtPositionX + 3, aAtPositionY, aOccupiedCoordinateCount, aOccupiedCoordinates);
  drawBox(inWindow, aAtPositionX + 4, aAtPositionY, aOccupiedCoordinateCount, aOccupiedCoordinates);
}
```

### Expected results

```
X: 4, Y: 4
X: 5, Y: 4
X: 6, Y: 4
X: 7, Y: 4
X: 8, Y: 4
```

### Actual results

```
realloc(): Invalid next size

core dumped
```

## Edit

```
          (*aOccupiedCoordinates)[*aOccupiedCoordinateCount].x = aAtPositionX;
          (*aOccupiedCoordinates)[*aOccupiedCoordinateCount].y = aAtPositionY;
```

or

```
          (*aOccupiedCoordinates)[newCount - 1].x = aAtPositionX;
          (*aOccupiedCoordinates)[newCount - 1].y = aAtPositionY;
```

shows

```
X: 4, Y: 4
X: -1300275184, Y: 21961
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
```

in `drawThreeHorizontalBoxes`.

Comment: Why are you using a double pointer for ` CoOrdinates** aOccupiedCoordinates`? It seems that you only have a 1D array of Coordinates

Comment: @RishikeshRaje: OP is passing the pointer around so that it can be realloced. The same is with the count, the idea is to update it inside the function. I agree it's not the best idea.

Comment: Atis, make your life simpler by defining a struct which represents a list of coordinates. Create it in a separate unit (c file), so that it has functions which operate on this list (add/remove elements, get count, etc). Ideally it should have a capacity which is slightly larger than the current count, and be automatically resized as needed. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3536261/69809) shows an example of such list, you would do the same thing but with coordinates instead of integers. Then when you test it, you can pass it around your code and worry about the higher-level problems.

Comment: @Groo That's an excellent suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is this:

```
(*aOccupiedCoordinates)[newCount].x = aAtPositionX;
(*aOccupiedCoordinates)[newCount].y = aAtPositionY;
```

Here `newCount` is the *size* of the "array", which will be one out of bounds of the allocated memory.

Use the old counter `*aOccupiedCoordinateCount` instead (or subtract one from `newCount` in the index).

---

A second problem is that you free the memory *inside* the loop where you print the values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < occupiedCoordinateCount; ++i)
  {
    printf("X: %d, Y: %d \n", occupiedCoordinates[i].x, occupiedCoordinates[i].y);
    free(occupiedCoordinates);
  }
```

The first iteration will free the memory, so each other iteration will use memory that isn't owned by you anymore, *and* try to free it *again*.

The `free` call should be *outside* of the loop.

Comment: Now it works prefectly if called once, but if I call it from `drawThreeHorizontalBoxes` I get this error  `X: 4, Y: 4
X: 335224848, Y: 22062
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted                 (core dumped) `

Comment: @atis Updated with the second problem

Comment: OH NO! I don't know how I missed that! Thanks for the help and your time.