# Linked list or "dynamic" array in C

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-arrays

I have a server and a client component, both written in C.
The servers saves the socket file descriptor into an integer variable - this is used later for closing the socket.

The server will have quite a few connections open at the same time and I would like to keep track of the socket file descriptors. The concept of linked and double linked lists is not new to me and I have already implemented it a few times. However, I have recently stumbled across a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536153/c-dynamically-growing-array) and now I am not sure if a linked list is the best way to go. Does this "dynamic" array have any downsides compared to the linked lists? When would I be using the "dynamic" array and when to use a linked list?

EDIT: To clarify - With "quite a few connections" I meant up to 100 simultaneous connections.

Comment: What is "quite a few" ? Dozends? Hundreds? Thousands?

Comment: if you always add/remove elements at the end of the list a dynamic array is faster and use less memory. If you add/remove elements elsewhere using an array you have to move elements which is expensive

Comment: If the number of connections is **maximum** hundred, then arrays can help, **but really, it depends on your use case**.