# Any append (Python) or push_back (C++) equivalent in C?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm looking for an "**append**" (Python) or "**push_back**" (C++) equivalent in C to fill an array of strings (char). Does it exists?

Comment: Short answer: Nope. Long answer: I'm sure some third party library has implemented stuff like this (maybe not published as a part of their API though), but the closest thing the C standard provides is `realloc`, which is both harder to use and needs more custom code to work with than the easy stuff from higher level languages.

Comment: This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536153/c-dynamically-growing-array

Comment: C isn't any different from C++ in this case (in regards to adding to arrays).

Comment: Basically, no. You have to do it yourself. There are no libraries to do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question doesn't make sense because you cannot add elements to an array in C. In C, you set the size of the array when you create it, and the size cannot change.

If you want to "append", you have to create a big array (e.g. 1000 items), and use a separate variable to remember how many items you're actually using (the rest are spare).

Comment: The most we can do is setting the last "unused/free" (whatever it means) element to a given value, but such a built-in function doesn't exist.