# how can i have a struct have an unknown size array member?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, flexible-array-member

im trying to make a sort of minesweeper clone in c, but i cant figure out how to create a variable length array member of a struct and initialize it.

my struct definitions

```c
typedef struct Cell
{
    Rectangle area;         // The area the cell covers
    bool hasMine;           // If the cell covers a mine
    bool covered;           // If the cell is currently covered
    int touching;           // How many mines the cell is touching
} Cell;

typedef struct Minefield
{
    int columns;        // The amount of columns
    int rows;           // The amount of rows
    int mines;          // The amount of mines
    Cell field[];       // An array of columns*rows Cells

} Minefield;
```

how im creating new instances of a Minefield

```c
Minefield NewGame(int columns, int rows, int mines)
{
    int i = 0;

    Cell cells[columns*rows];

    for (i=0; i < columns*rows; i++) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        if (i == 0) {
            Rectangle area = (Rectangle){0, 0, cellsize, cellsize};
            cells[i] = (Cell){area, false, true, 0};
        }
        else {
            Cell previous = cells[i-1];

            x = previous.area.x + cellsize;
            y = previous.area.y + cellsize;

            Rectangle area = (Rectangle){x, y, cellsize, cellsize};
            cells[i] = (Cell){area, false, true, 0};
        }
        
    }

    Minefield field = (Minefield){columns, rows, mines, cells};
    return field;
}
```

im new to c, ive done some googling and ive come across some very similar questions, but i cant really understand them or the examples they give. i think you can do what my errendous code is trying to do (or something very similar) with a gcc extension, but i want my code to be portable. how can i have a struct have an unknown size array member?

Comment: Google _flexible array member_.

Comment: Alternatively, include a pointer to `Cell` in the struct, and dynamically allocate the memory for an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called `flexible array member`. It's usually used with dynamically allocated objects. However, you cannot return `Minefield` by value. The compiler will copy only `sizeof(Minefield)` data what is the size of object if length of array `Minefield::field` was `0`.

You can do:

```
Minefield* NewGame(int columns, int rows, int mines)
{
    Cell cells[columns*rows];
    ...
    // allocate memory for Minefield and cells array just after it
    Minefield* minefield = malloc(sizeof(*minefield) + sizeof cells);
    if (!minefield) { ... error handling ... }

    // set normal fields using compund literal
    *minefield = (Minefield){columns, rows, mines};

    // copy cells `array` to `minefield->field` array
    memcpy(minefield->field, cells, sizeof cells);

    return minefield;
}
```

The `memcpy` can be avoided by first allocating `Minefield` and writing directly to `field` member.

```
Minefield* NewGame(int columns, int rows, int mines)
{
    Minefield* minefield = malloc(sizeof(Minefield) + rows * columns * sizeof(Cell));
    if (!minefield) { ... error handling ... }
    *minefield = (Minefield){columns, rows, mines};

    Cell *cells = minefield->field;
    ...
    return minefield;
}
```

Comment: when will minefield be false (!minefield evaluates to true)? is it when the system cannot allocate memory for it?

Comment: @mmxjohnson  `minifield` is false when it is equal to `NULL`. This indicates that `malloc()` failed, usually due to the lack of memory or due to large fragmentation (it could not find a contiguous chunk of desired size).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, C doesn't have any built-in dynamic array like python. However, if you want to use some dynamic array either you can implement your self or you can see the answer to that link [C dynamically growing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536153/c-dynamically-growing-array) which explains that you need to have starting array with a default size, and then you can increase the size of the array which depends on your algorithm. After you import that header file provided by @casablance, you can simply use it for your minesweeper game.