# My array creation program returns value 3221225477 after inputing about 8 integers

Tags: arrays, c, while-loop

The program`s first task is to create an array without knowing the number of elements beforehand (the user inputs integers until 0 is input). I tried making this with a while loop, but after inputting a certain amount of integers, the loop ends and I get the 3221225477 value.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
    int input=1,n=1,i=0;
    int array[n];
    while(input!=0){
        printf("Input a number (zero for end): ");
        scanf("%d",&input);
        array[i]=input;
        if(input!=0){
            n++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nArray: ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",array[i]);
}
```

I tried adding the & sign in row 8, but it just gave back errors for invalid conversions and lvalues.

Comment: Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Error `C0000005` is an access violation error. Your `int array[n];` has only one element – changing `n` later has no effect on the array size.

Comment: Get yourself a proper C textbook. Don't try to learn by looking at random examples on the internet.

Comment: Instead of using `scanf()` (and you really __must__ inspect its return value!), you should create a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem without needing additional input.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems in this code.

```
main()
```

This is not legal in C. All functions need to be specified with a type. The old "implicit int" rule is not a part of the language since 2011, and was deprecated and frowned upon long before that date.

```
    int input=1,n=1,i=0;
    int array[n];
```

This defines an array of size 1. Note, this does **not** define an array if size `n` that tracks changes in the value of `n` and grows or shrinks accordingly. There is no such thing in C. If you want an array that grows or shrinks, you need code that dynamically allocates an array and resizes it as needed. See for example [C dynamically growing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536153/c-dynamically-growing-array).

```
    scanf("%d",&input);
```

Always check the return value of `scanf`. Better still, don't use `scanf`. See [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Comment: Implicit `int` went the way of the dodo in C99, not C11.  See C99 [Forward ¶5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#Forewordp5).

Answer (score 1):

Because you declared as `n=1`, `int array[n];` has only 1 element. The indices begin with 0, so `array[1]` and above are out-of-range and must not be accessed.

Allocate enough elements like `int array[100000];` or use dynamic allocation via `malloc`, `realloc`, etc.

Note that allocating too large an array statically on the stack may cause a runtime error (depending on the environment), so if this happens, you should reduce the size or switch to dynamic allocation.

Comment: In this particular case, they could avoid the stack issues by putting the array in global memory (by declaring it outside `main`, or by declaring it `static` inside `main`), since `main`, while technically reentrant, will not be reentered in any sane beginner level exercise. It still wouldn't grow dynamically of course; if they need that, `malloc`+`realloc` it is.